# Portable way to find out if a command exists (C/C++)

Tags: c, path, system, executable, popen

C standard library provides functions `system` and `popen` to run a command. But is there a portable way to detect if a command exists?

Comment: By "command", it looks like you mean "another program on the user's machine"? Can you confirm this is the usage you mean?

Answer (score 15):

For POSIX systems I found this to work very well (I'm checking for avconv in this example):

```
if (system("which avconv > /dev/null 2>&1")) {
    // Command doesn't exist...
} else {
    // Command does exist, do something with it...
}
```

The Redirect to /dev/null is simply to avoid anything being printed to stdout. It relies on the exit value from the which command alone.

Comment: The redirection was what other answers were missing. +1 for  avoiding which output

Comment: This is both slow and relies on the existence of `which` - that is not necessary. In fact... IIANM, `which` is [not every required](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html) by POSIX to exist - correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 6):

No, there isn't any standard C function for that.

The Unix-only solution is to split `getenv("PATH")` on `:` (colon), and try to find the command executable (with the `stat` function) in the directories.

Some more details on what happens on Unix: [execvp(3) in musl](https://fossies.org/linux/musl/src/process/execvp.c) (a libc for Linux) `getenv("PATH")` on `:` (colon), and tries to run the program with the execve(2) system call (rather than the stat(2) system call). It's not feasible to emulate this 100% with stat(2), because for example execve(2) may fail with ENOEXEC (Exec format error) if it doesn't recognize the file format, which depends on kernel settings (including [binfmt-misc](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.html) module on Linux).

Some more details on what a Unix shell does. All the logic in the Dash shell is in [exec.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git/tree/src/exec.c). The *shellexec* function (called by the `exec` builtin) is similar to execvp(3) in musl (split `PATH` on `:` + execve(2)). The `type` builtin calls the *describe_command* function, which calls *find_command*, which does: split `PATH` on `:` + stat(2) + regular-file-check + execute-permission-check. The regular-file-check (near `S_ISREG`) checks that the filename is a regular file (i.e. rather than a directory, pipe or device etc.). The execute-permission-check (near `getegid`) checks approximately that the current process has execute permission on the file, by checking the relevant executable bit in `st_mode` returned by stat(2). Please note that these checks are qlwo only approximations, the ENOEXEC error above also applies here.

Comment: +1. On Windows, it's a bit different: break on ";" not ":", and you need to check files ending with (at least) ".exe", ".com" and ".bat". In fact it's trickier than that -- as I recall, cmd.exe searches for .com files first in ALL directories, then for .exe files in ALL directories, etc. I don't recall the details unfortunately, but it *is* different than the order used by CreateProcess().

Comment: On Windows, there are many more executable extensions, such as .pif, .lnk, .vbs, .scr etc. It would be better to find an API call to list all of them instead of hardcoding them.

Comment: Get the active list of executable extension from the *PATHEXT* environment variable on Win32: https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Windows/development/environment-variables/PATHEXT

Comment: In Python, `os.pathsep` is `':'` on Unix and `';'` on Windows. Standard C and C++ don't predefine this constant. `std::filesystem::path::preferred_separator` is something else (`'/'` or `'\\'`) in C++17.

Answer (score 5):

While I don't think there is a completely portable way to do this (some systems don't even support command interpreters), `system()` does return 0 if there were no errors while running your command. I suppose you could just try running your command and then check the return value of system.

To check if a command interpreter is available, call `system( NULL )` and check for a non-zero value.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to scan all the paths stored in the `PATH` variable, scanning for the `mathsat` executable:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  struct stat sb;
  string delimiter = ":";
  string path = string(getenv("PATH"));
  size_t start_pos = 0, end_pos = 0;

  while ((end_pos = path.find(':', start_pos)) != string::npos)
    {
      string current_path =
        path.substr(start_pos, end_pos - start_pos) + "/mathsat";

      if ((stat(mathsat_path.c_str(), &sb) == 0) && (sb.st_mode & S_IXOTH))
        {
          cout << "Okay" << endl;
          return EXIT_SUCCESS;
         }

      start_pos = end_pos + 1;
     }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This is great. It excludes the last item in the path though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fully-portable way to do this in C, as @pts' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/890903/1593077) explains. But if you assume a [POSIX environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1780599/1593077), you can do this.

First, let's [recall how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76176968/1593077) to check whether a path designates an executable file (with C and POSIX):

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int is_executable_file(char const * file_path) 
{
    struct stat sb;
    return 
        (stat(file_path, &sb) == 0) &&  
        S_ISREG(sb.st_mode) && 
        (access(file_path, X_OK) == 0);
}
```

Now let us use this function to check the paths obtained by concatenating the command name to all elements of the PATH environment variable:

```c
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int is_executable_file(char const * file_path);

char const * strchrnul_(char const * haystack, size_t haystack_length, char needle)
{
    char const * strchr_result = strchr(haystack, needle);
    return (strchr_result != NULL) ? strchr_result : haystack + haystack_length;
}

int executable_is_on_path(char const* executable_basename)
{
    char const * const path_env_var = getenv("PATH");
    // You may want to decide on your own policy regarding behavior when there is no PATH
    if (path_env_var == NULL) { return is_executable(executable_basename); }
    const size_t path_env_var_len = strlen(path_env_var);
    if (path_env_var_len == 0) { return is_executable(executable_basename); }
    const size_t basename_len = strlen(executable_basename);

    // Allocate the maximum possible length of an executable path using a directory in the PATH string,
    // so that we don't need to re-allocate later
    char * executable_path = (char*) malloc(path_env_var_len + basename_len + 2);
    if (executable_path == NULL) { return false; } // or you can throw an exception, or exit etc.

    for (char const * token_start = path_env_var; token_start < path_env_var + path_env_var_len; ) {
        static char const delimiter = ':';
        char const *token_end = strchrnul_(token_start, path_env_var_len, delimiter);
        // composing the full path of the prospective executable
        {
            off_t token_len = token_end - token_start;
            strncpy(executable_path, token_start, token_len);
            executable_path[token_len] = '/';
            strcpy(executable_path + token_len + 1, executable_basename);
            executable_path[basename_len + token_len + 1] = '\0';
        }
        if (is_executable(executable_path)) { 
            free(executable_path);
            return true;
        }
        token_start = token_end + 1;
    }
    free(executable_path);
    return false;
}
```

If you were using C++, you would have a somewhat easier time with string, filesystem and path operations; but this is pure C (in fact, it's C89).

Answer (score 0):

A variation of what Ben Collins said, but using POSIX `command -v` instead of `which` which is not part of POSIX.

You can do this by running the command:

```bash
command -v CMD_TO_CHECK > /dev/null 2>&1
```

- The `-v` flags tells `command` to not execute the file and would normally also print the file path to `stdout`.
- The `> /dev/null` redirects `stdout` output to a null stream, meaning it is just discarded. This way we won't have clutter in our program's `stdout`.
- The `2>&1` merges `stderr` into `stdout` by redirecting the file descriptor `2`'s output into `1`'s, meaning `stderr` won't be printed either. On my system `command -v` doesn't ever seem to print to `stderr` but I don't know if this would be true for every implementation.

If the program is found, `system` returns `0`, otherwise it will return something greater than `0` if the program doesn't exist. This is why when checking, you should use `system(...) == 0`, or alternatively `!system(...)`.

Example to check if Clang exists:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
// ...

if( !system("command -v clang > /dev/null 2>&1") )
{
    // The command exists!
}
else
{
    // Doesn't exist
}
```

Using this you can make a function to check if an arbitrary program exists:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int programExists(const char *name)
{
    char buffer[512];

    snprintf(
        buffer,
        sizeof buffer,
        "command -v %s > /dev/null 2>&1",
        name
    );

    return !system( buffer );
}

int main()
{
    printf("GCC ");
    if( programExists("gcc") ) printf("exists!\n");
    else printf("not found.\n");

    printf("obscureprogram ");
    if( programExists("obscureprogram") ) printf("exists!\n");
    else printf("not found.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

or use the first example to avoid the buffering and using `snprintf`.

Answer (score -1):

here is a snippet from my code that i use to look for existing commands in the system using `PATH` from environment variables.

first i get the `PATH` variable then i split it using `:` then i store it in 2d array and return in `get_path(...)`.

after that i join the string cmd with each path in PATH variable and check if i can access it using `access(2)` function if the file exist then i found the path to the executable and i return it else i print error with `perror()` and return NULL.

```
char    **get_paths(char **envp)
{
    while (*envp)
    {
        if (ft_strncmp(*envp, "PATH=", 5) == 0)
            return (ft_split(*envp + 5, ':'));
        envp++;
    }
    return (NULL);
}

char    *cmd_file(char **envp, char *cmd)
{
    char    **paths;
    char    *path_tmp;
    char    *file;

    paths = envp;
    if (access(cmd, X_OK) == 0)
        return (ft_strdup(cmd));
    while (*paths && cmd)
    {
        path_tmp = ft_strjoin(*paths, "/");
        file = ft_strjoin(path_tmp, cmd);
        free(path_tmp);
        if (access(file, X_OK) == 0)
            return (file);
        free(file);
        paths++;
    }
    perror(cmd);
    return (NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    char **paths;
    char *cmd;
    paths = get_paths(envp);
    cmd = cmd_file(paths, argv[1]);
    printf("%s\n", cmd);
}
```

Comment: Please add your includes. I don't know of functions named `ft_whatever`.

Comment: ft_ functions are custom made functions most of them are from the standard c library just remove the ft and include the standard c library.
you can find ft_ functions definitions here:
https://github.com/Milimas/libft