# What is the meaning of "POSIX"?

Tags: unix, posix, standards, terminology, portability

What exactly is POSIX? I have read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) but I still don't understand.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11983/what-exactly-is-posix

Comment: quick definition reference - http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/POSIX-Portable-Operating-System-Interface

Comment: Just since it might help some people: Two examples of Unix-y OSes are BSD and GNU/Linux. > BSD is a 'unix-like' complete OS, with its own kernel and its own userland (no linux kernel nor GNU). GNU/Linux and *BSD family (FreeBSD, OpenBSD and NetBSD) are 'unix-like' OS, they behave like Unix.

Comment: "I read the Wikipedia article but I still don't understand" - that's a good outcome. The real problem is when you read the Wikipedia article and then think that you do understand.

Comment: Richard Stallman explains "POSIX": [https://opensource.com/article/19/7/what-posix-richard-stallman-explains](https://opensource.com/article/19/7/what-posix-richard-stallman-explains)

Answer (score 756, accepted):

[POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) is a family of standards, specified by the [IEEE](http://www.ieee.org/portal/site), to clarify and make uniform the application programming interfaces (and ancillary issues, such as command line shell utilities) provided by Unix-y operating systems.

When you write your programs to rely on POSIX standards, you can be pretty sure to be able to port them easily among a large family of Unix derivatives (including Linux, but not limited to it!); if and when you use some Linux API that's not standardized as part of Posix, you will have a harder time if and when you want to port that program or library to other Unix-y systems (e.g., MacOSX) in the future.

Comment: 1. You mean POSIX says that all *nix OSes (kernels) should have atleast these set of system calls. right? 
2. does WINDOWS/MAC follows POSIX? If/Ifnot does WINDOWS (95,98,2000,xp,vista,7) is following some common standard (may be their own proprietary) standard? In other words, POSIX in Microsoft world ==?

Comment: No, the standard is at an API level -- each specified call can be implemented in the kernel, or in the C library in terms of another call, and that's just fine for Posix (and for your programs too;-). MacOSX is Posix compliant, see http://devworld.apple.com/leopard/overview/osfoundations.html . For Windows, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#POSIX_for_Windows : Posix compliance is currently included in Enterprise and Ultimate editions only (not in the cheaper ones!-), though you can get partways w/Cygwin, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin .

Comment: Your comment is flawed, as Microsoft's market share on desktops, at least, makes it "what the world follows".

Comment: I think what claws meant is that Microsoft doesn't put much effort into being interoperable with other platforms.

Comment: It's made all the more funnier by the fact that the only reason Windows and Word got off was that they spent ridiculous amounts of time making sure every application of the leading platform then was compatible with their product...

Comment: Is Ubuntu POSIX-compliant? I'm having a nightmare trying to compile some regular C99 code written on my Mac for an Ubuntu server to run. Stuff like `usleep` are giving me errors.

Comment: @claws I think MS finally understood it and changing, now atleast by supporting open source!

Comment: @deltaray [embrace, extend, and extinguish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend_and_extinguish). MS java (non-standard java.util. java.security, java.io, java.lang, and java.awt), Internet Explorer (almost said 'exploder'), and .NET (yes, I know they have released partial source for .NET, but it's license is restrictive and it's NOT a linux port yet. Mono is incomplete). Also, [exFAT patents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT#Restrictive_licensing_and_software_patents). You are absolutely correct.

Comment: @NidhinDavid they completely removed their POSIX subsystem in windows 8.1. They don't change for the better. And besides opening the .NET code with a restrictive license (specifically you can't use it in non-.NET projects), what has MS done to 'support open source'? Last I knew, exFAT was still proprietary, and it's the new standard filesystem for large USB drives and large SD cards.

Comment: I think OSX is POSIX-compliant.

Comment: OSX is POSIX-compliant, MSWindows is not, @9000 Ubuntu is also not POSIX-compliant

Comment: `Microsoft's market share on desktops, at least, makes it "what the world follows"` - 

Interesting to note how much things have changed since this comment from 2009 :)

Comment: @Sz. 512 is closer now. This answer is suddenly popular probably because a HNQ linked to it.

Comment: Well, looks like they went in the right direction at least with .NET (and some other projects). See https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet , now seems to include .Net Core. Everything seems MIT or Apache 2 licensed.

Comment: Archived link for the curious: https://web.archive.org/web/20080509070100/devworld.apple.com/leopard/overview/osfoundations.html

Comment: @sudo `usleep` is no POSIX API, it is BSD API. Linux is largely POSIX compliant, macOS is perfectly POSIX compliant, but both also support their own, non portable APIs. In case of macOS that is BSD API and Apples own frameworks, in case of Linux these are Linux specific APIs. If you want fully portal code, you need to limit yourself to POSIX API. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799 - select "System Interfaces" top left and then again "bottom left" to get a list of all POSIX API functions.

Answer (score 696):

**The most important things [POSIX 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/nfindex.html) defines**

1. [C API](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/contents.html)

   Greatly [extends ANSI C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376837/difference-bewteen-c-standard-library-and-c-posix-library/37969420#37969420) with things like:

   - more file operations: `mkdir`, `dirname`, `symlink`, `readlink`, `link` (hardlinks), [`poll()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444679/how-does-the-poll-c-linux-function-work/44127590#44127590), `stat`, `sync`, [`nftw()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436841/how-to-recursively-list-directories-in-c-on-linux/29402705)
   - process and threads: `fork`, `execl`, [`wait`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248031/meaning-of-dollar-question-mark-in-shell-scripts/57303942#57303942), `pipe`, semaphors [`sem_*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400820/how-to-use-posix-semaphores-on-forked-processes-in-c/52042490#52042490), shared memory (`shm_*`), `kill`, scheduling parameters (`nice`, `sched_*`), `sleep`, `mkfifo`, [`setpgid()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108953/how-does-ctrl-c-terminate-a-child-process/52042970#52042970)
   - networking: [`socket()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208299/how-to-make-an-http-get-request-in-c-without-libcurl/35680609#35680609)
   - memory management: `mmap`, `mlock`, `mprotect`, `madvise`, [`brk()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988487/what-does-the-brk-system-call-do/31082353#31082353)
   - utilities: regular expressions (`reg*`)

   Those APIs also determine underlying system concepts on which they depend, e.g. `fork` requires a concept of a process.

   Many [Linux system calls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421750/where-do-you-find-the-syscall-table-for-linux) exist to implement a specific POSIX C API function and make Linux compliant, e.g. `sys_write`, `sys_read`, ... Many of those syscalls also have Linux-specific extensions however.

   Major Linux desktop implementation: glibc, which in many cases just provides a shallow wrapper to system calls.
2. [CLI utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html)

   E.g.: `cd`, `ls`, `echo`, ...

   Many utilities are direct shell front ends for a corresponding C API function, e.g. `mkdir`.

   Major Linux desktop implementation: GNU Coreutils for the small ones, separate GNU projects for the big ones: `sed`, `grep`, `awk`, ... Some CLI utilities are implemented by Bash [as built-ins](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11454/what-is-the-difference-between-a-builtin-command-and-one-that-is-not).
3. [Shell language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18)

   E.g., `a=b; echo "$a"`

   Major Linux desktop implementation: [GNU Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)).
4. [Environment variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08)

   E.g.: `HOME`, `PATH`.

   `PATH` [search semantics are specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01), including [how slashes prevent `PATH` search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331075/why-do-you-need-dot-slash-before-executable-or-script-name-to-run-it-in-bas/6331085#6331085).
5. [Program exit status](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08)

   ANSI C says `0` or `EXIT_SUCCESS` for success, `EXIT_FAILURE` for failure, and leaves the rest implementation defined.

   POSIX adds:

   - `126`: command found but not executable.
   - `127`: command not found.
   - `> 128`: terminated by a signal.

     But POSIX does not seem to specify the `128 + SIGNAL_ID` rule used by Bash: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99112/default-exit-code-when-process-is-terminated

   See also: [What is the meaning of `$?` (dollar question mark) in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248031/meaning-of-dollar-question-mark-in-shell-scripts/57303942#57303942)
6. [Regular expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09)

   There are two types: BRE (Basic) and ERE (Extended). Basic is deprecated and only kept to not break APIs.

   Those are implemented by C API functions, and used throughout CLI utilities, e.g. `grep` accepts BREs by default, and EREs with `-E`.

   E.g.: `echo 'a.1' | grep -E 'a.[[:digit:]]'`

   Major Linux implementation: glibc implements the functions under [regex.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/regex.h.html) which programs like `grep` can use as backend.
7. [Directory structure](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap10.html#tag_10)

   E.g.: `/dev/null`, `/tmp`

   The Linux [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) greatly extends POSIX.
8. [Filenames](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_267)

   - `/` is the path separator
   - `NUL` cannot be used
   - `.` is `cwd`, `..` parent
   - portable filenames

     - use at most max 14 chars and 256 for the full path
     - can only contain: `a-zA-Z0-9._-`

   See also: [what is posix compliance for filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550253/what-is-posix-compliance-for-filesystem)
9. [Command line utility API conventions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html)

   Not mandatory, used by POSIX, but almost nowhere else, notably not in GNU. But true, it is too restrictive, e.g. single letter flags only (e.g. `-a`), no double hyphen long versions (e.g. `--all`).

   A few widely used conventions:

   - `-` means stdin where a file is expected
   - `--` terminates flags, e.g. `ls -- -l` to list a directory named `-l`

   See also: [Are there standards for Linux command line switches and arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957222/are-there-standards-for-linux-command-line-switches-and-arguments)
10. "POSIX ACLs" (Access Control Lists), e.g. as used as backend for [`setfacl`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487527/give-specific-user-permission-to-write-to-a-folder-using-w-notation/809562#809562).

    This [was withdrawn](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489820/why-was-posix-1e-withdrawn) but it was implemented in several OSes, including [in Linux with `setxattr`](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/system-call-to-set-file-acls-in-linux-537615/#post5988355).

**Who conforms to POSIX?**

Many systems follow POSIX closely, but few are actually certified by the Open Group which maintains the standard. Notable certified ones include:

- OS X (Apple) X stands for both 10 and UNIX. Was the first Apple POSIX system, released circa 2001. See also: [Is OSX a POSIX OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785516/is-osx-a-posix-os)
- AIX (IBM)
- HP-UX (HP)
- Solaris (Oracle)

Most Linux distros are very compliant, but not certified because they don't want to pay the compliance check. [Inspur's K-UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inspur_K-UX) and [Huawei's EulerOS](https://www.huawei.com/en/press-events/news/2016/9/huawei-kunlun-euleros-unix-certification) are two certified examples.

The official list of certified systems be found at: https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/ and also at the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#POSIX-oriented_operating_systems).

**Windows**

Windows implemented POSIX on some of its professional distributions.

Since it was an optional feature, programmers could not rely on it for most end user applications.

Support was deprecated in Windows 8:

- [Where does Microsoft Windows' 7 POSIX implementation currently stand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746043/where-does-microsoft-windows-7-posix-implementation-currently-stand)
- https://superuser.com/questions/495360/does-windows-8-still-implement-posix
- Feature request: https://windows.uservoice.com/forums/265757-windows-feature-suggestions/suggestions/6573649-full-posix-support

In 2016 a new official Linux-like API called "Windows Subsystem for Linux" was announced. It includes Linux system calls, ELF running, parts of the `/proc` filesystem, Bash, GCC, (TODO likely glibc?), `apt-get` and more: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/P488 so I believe that it will allow Windows to run much, if not all, of POSIX. However, it is focused on developers / deployment instead of end users. In particular, there were no plans to allow access to the Windows GUI.

Historical overview of the official Microsoft POSIX compatibility: http://brianreiter.org/2010/08/24/the-sad-history-of-the-microsoft-posix-subsystem/

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) is a well known GPL third-party project for that "provides substantial POSIX API functionality" for Windows, but requires that you "rebuild your application from source if you want it to run on Windows". [MSYS2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/) is a related project that seems to add more functionality on top of Cygwin.

If the only thing from POSIX that you need are the command line utilities, also consider: https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs which re-implements a bunch of CLI utilities in Node.js, which already essentially implements a portability layer for the simpler system calls like `mkdir` etc. Many people use that project in the `package.json` of their project to allow running the project on Windows as well. Of course, it requires users to install the Node.js runtime, but given the popularity of Node.js, I don't expect that to break/be hard to satisfy anytime soon.

**Android**

Android has its own C library (Bionic) which does not fully support POSIX as of Android O: [Is Android POSIX-compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604455/is-android-posix-compatible)

**Bonus level**

The [Linux Standard Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) further extends POSIX.

Use the non-frames indexes, they are much more readable and searchable: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/nfindex.html

Get a full zipped version of the HTML pages for grepping:  [Where is the list of the POSIX C API functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453993/is-there-a-listing-of-the-posix-api-functions/45832939#45832939)

Comment: Fantastic examples, if you had a definition as well like the accepted answer this would be the top answer.

Comment: @Marc thanks! I try not to repeat what is said in other answers as people probably have already read those and to avoid duplication ;-) This is a known dilemma: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305645/do-we-want-single-complete-answers?cb=1

Comment: Good idea to actually explain what POSIX covers (and what not).

Comment: Everywhere in the literature, references to "POSIX compliance" pop up, and the typical definition of POSIX people find is "a set of standards for interoperability among Unix-like operating systems". Although useful, this definition leaves a lot of doubts, specially regarding the features that are expected to interoperate. Sure, you can go and read the whole POSIX spec to delve into the details (and spend a whole lot of time on that). But, this answer provides the much needed summary to get the big picture on the scope of POSIX. Special thanks to Ciro for taking the time to write it!

Comment: It might also be good to add some Posix guarantees about integer types.  I don't know exactly what is and isn't specified, but I know that at minimum Posix requires the existence of uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t and the corresponding signed types.  I'm not sure if it guarantees that types like "int" have power-of-two sizes and that a system won't do something nasty like have an "int" with 32 value bits, 1 sign bit, and 31 padding bits [so incrementing a uint32_t could yield UB]; if you have the Standard handy it might be nice to say what is and isn't guaranteed in that regard.

Comment: @supercat `uintX_t` and signed versions are present in C99 on which POSIX 7 is based, so those are guaranteed, so I don't think it's worth mentioning. If `int` is power of 2, I don't know, that probably deserves a separate question: I'm sure it exists already, but quick Google didn't find it. Ping me if you find it. :-) If POSIX extends C there, let's link to it.

Comment: @CiroSantilli巴拿馬文件六四事件法轮功: A C99 implementation which has both a 16-bit unsigned type which can hold values 0 to 65535, and a 16-bit signed type that holds -32768 to 32767, is required to define uint16_t and int16_t.  A C99 implementation which e.g. has a 9-bit character type cannot define them.  I know Posix mandates that `char` be 8 bits, and I *think* it mandates the existence of those other types, but I'm not positive on the latter point.

Comment: @supercat ah, I didn't know that `uintX_t` were optional! Mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13413892/895245 which you also answered. If you find a conclusive quote of a POSIX extension for that, edit an answer there, and I'll link to it.

Comment: Why is Microsoft trying to be compatible with linux instead of BSD? the GPL hates commercial use, and they' don't support POSIX 100%, unlike BSD.

Comment: @MarcusJ I know nothing about BSD, but I think this is the reason: https://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=linux,bsd :-)

Comment: The brk() and sbrk() legacy functions were removed in issue 6 of POSIX.

Answer (score 82):

[POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) is:

> POSIX (pronounced /ˈpɒzɪks/) or
>   "Portable Operating System Interface
>   [for Unix]"[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) is the name of a family
>   of related standards specified by the
>   IEEE to define the application
>   programming interface (API), along
>   with shell and utilities interfaces
>   for software compatible with variants
>   of the Unix operating system, although
>   the standard can apply to any
>   operating system.

Basically it was a set of measures to ease the pain of development and usage of different flavours of UNIX by having a (mostly) common API and utilities. Limited POSIX compliance also extended to various versions of Windows.

Comment: 1. You mean POSIX says that all *nix OSes (kernels) should have atleast these set of system calls. right? 2. does WINDOWS/MAC follows POSIX? If/Ifnot does WINDOWS (95,98,2000,xp,vista,7) is following some common standard (may be their own proprietary) standard? In other words, POSIX in Microsoft world ==?

Comment: Basically it "was" a set of measures to ease the pain of development.
WAS??

Comment: I questioned the use of the word *was*, too, but it's debatable.  To answer your questions: (1) no, POSIX has absolutely zilch to do with the kernel, it just describes how it should operate; (2) OS X is BSD and is quite POSIX-compliant, but there are gray areas.  Windows 2008 is closest to POSIX complaint; there is no equivalent of POSIX in the Microsoft world.

Comment: Where can I read this specs? I just want to have glance at them.

Comment: @claws: Don't mean to dirty up the area under cletus's answer...but. I linked POSIX.1-2008 in my answer...right there.

Comment: @Jed Smith, there are no gray areas in terms of Mac OS X compliance; Mac OS X is certified compliant with the Single UNIX Specification v3, a standard of which POSIX is a subset.

Comment: @claws, you can read the Single UNIX Specification, of which POSIX is a subset, at the following link: http://www.unix.org/single_unix_specification/

Comment: That use of was is wrong. POSIX _is_ a standard, the latest version of which is IEEE Std 1003.1-2008 and ISO/IEC 9945:2009.

Answer (score 54):

Let me give the churlish "unofficial" explanation.

POSIX is a set of standards which attempts to distinguish "UNIX" and UNIX-like systems from those which are incompatible with them.  It was created by the U.S. government for procurement purposes.  The idea was that the U.S. federal procurements needed a way to legally specify the requirements for various sorts of bids and contracts in a way that could be used to exclude systems to which a given existing code base or programming staff would NOT be portable.

Since POSIX was written post facto ... to describe a loosely similar set of competing systems ... it was NOT written in a way that could be implemented.

So, for example, Microsoft's NT was written with enough POSIX conformance to qualify for some bids ... even though the POSIX subsystem was essentially useless in terms of practical portability and compatibility with UNIX systems.

Various other standards for UNIX have been written over the decades.  Things like the SPEC1170 (specified eleven hundred and seventy function calls which had to be implemented compatibly) and various incarnations of the SUS (Single UNIX Specification).

For the most part these "standards" have been inadequate to any practical technical application.  They mostly exist for argumentation, legal wrangling and other dysfunctional reasons.

Comment: Then how come Linux implement most of POSIX, including many of the extensions?

Comment: @ninjalj: Linux was written to implement a practical set of UNIX-like functions.  Doing so while conforming to POSIX makes perfect sense.  However, my point was that POSIX wasn't created as a specification for implementing new operating systems ... it was created as a way for U.S. government procurement staff to distinguish among those which qualified for certain categories in bids from those which wouldn't.

The focus in Linux is to provide the usable features in a way which is reasonable compatible, robust and performant.  POSIX is not quite an accident along the way.

Comment: Rather ingenious of you to claim that the POSIX was written post facto!  That is the hallmark of a good standards development organization (SDO) where consensus is not achieved until at least one conformant implementation exists.

Comment: @fpmurphy: Creating an ex post facto specification based on one or two interoperable implementations is the norm for IETF ... networking protocol standards which interact over intentionally loose couplings.

It hasn't been a successful process for OS standardization.  The API between programs and the system (kernel or microkernel and its subsystem servers) is far more tightly coupled than clients and servers or peers over networks.  (I'm not saying it's impossible; merely pointing out that there are differences and the history hasn't shown the latter to be promising).

Comment: It was developed by the IEEE. If it was really developed by the US Government it would have been a Federal Information Processing Standard (FIPS), like many others.

Comment: The efforts by IEEE to specify POSIX back in 1985 were spurred by the U.S. Government. Do some research, read a history book or something.

Answer (score 34):

POSIX is a standard for operating systems that was supposed to make it easier to write cross-platform software. It's an especially big deal in the world of Unix.

Comment: It isn't just "supposed to" make it easier to write cross-platform code, it does make it easier to write cross-platform code. The only exception is Windows, because Microsoft thinks it is somehow better than everyone else and does not need to comply. However, I predict this will work against them, especially as Mac and Linux gain more market share. If they really are for the "developers, developers, developers", they will realize that developers want UNIX compliance.

Comment: Based on what I've heard from people who work with it much more closely than I ever did, it may have made things easier, but it certainly wasn't sufficient for the write-once, run-on-any-POSIX impression most people get when they hear it's a "standard" for operating systems.

Comment: They don't think they're "better than everyone else"; they know they're *bigger* than everyone else.  That's also why they'll change their tune as they lose market share.  It's not unique to them, e.g., Netscape started caring a lot more about web standards when they were no longer the most popular.

Comment: Writing an application to use only POSIX APIs makes it much easier to port between different Unix and Unix-like operating systems.  However it is a lowest common denominator consensus standard - so utilities or applications that are operating system or hardware specific will usually require some rewriting.

Comment: @Ken and that's why we shouldn't let Google's chromium get too comfy.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan unfortunately, *inx users are still adamantly divided on how to maintain and develop software (see Linux display managers, Linux gaming, Linux patching methods, Linux package managers) where Microsoft seems to be standardizing across platforms

Comment: @IanSmith I think we are referring to different things. In terms of how I think of things, I make an intentional distinction between an OS distribution and the OS, itself. The distribution is the user-facing product; the OS, itself, is the developer-facing product. And the reality is that, from a developer standpoint, standardization of the system libraries greatly simplifies things. MSFT has taken note of this and is trying to improve app availability by heading in this direction: https://www.theverge.com/2019/5/6/18534687/microsoft-windows-10-linux-kernel-feature

Answer (score 29):

POSIX is a set of standards put forth by IEEE and The Open Group that describes how an ideal Unix would operate. Programmers, users, and administrators can all become familiar with the POSIX document, and expect a POSIX-complaint Unix to provide all of the standard facilities mentioned.

Since every Unix does things a little differently -- Solaris, Mac OS X, IRIX, BSD, and Linux all have their quirks -- POSIX is especially useful to those in the industry as it defines a standard environment to operate in.  For example, most of the functions in the C library are based in POSIX; a programmer can, therefore, use one in his application and expect it to behave the same across most Unices.

However, the divergent areas of Unix are typically the focus, rather than the standard ones.

The great thing about POSIX is that you're welcome to read it yourself:

> [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)

Issue 7 is known as POSIX.1-2008, and there are new things in there -- however, Google-fu for POSIX.1 and such will allow you to see the entire history behind what Unix is.

Comment: I think you are using the term "UNIX" incorrectly. UNIX now refers to the Single UNIX Specification, and any UNIX operating system is an operating system that conforms to the Single UNIX Specification. Perhaps you mean UNIX-like?

Comment: @Michael: Given your comments in other answers, you're obviously a very polarized person with opinions that aren't exactly constructive. This specific comment is very pedantic, and my meaning was conveyed regardless of the choice of a label that you might disagree with.  Also, Windows is POSIX compliant in the higher-end versions.  Take a breath and step back, please.

Comment: @Jed Smith, strong opinions aside, the implication of the post is that some operating systems that are certified UNIX compliant are not... so, I think it is fair to say that that is misleading. Also, with regard to Windows, so long as there are editions that are not compliant, developers cannot rely on POSIX when targeting the Windows platform, thereby negating the entire purpose of having POSIX.

Comment: Unix is an operating system.  UNIX is a brand held by The Open Group.  Systems that are certified to either the UNIX95, UNIX98 or UNIX03 branding profiles, of which conformance to a particular version of the Single UNIX Specification forms the majority of the branding requirements, can use use the term UNIX.

Answer (score 9):

> In 1985, individuals from companies throughout the computer industry
>   joined together to develop the POSIX (Portable Operating System
>   Interface for Computer Environments) standard, which is based largely
>   on the UNIX System V Interface Definition (SVID) and other earlier
>   standardization efforts. These efforts were spurred by the U.S.
>   government, which needed a standard computing environment to minimize
>   its training and procurement costs. Released in 1988, POSIX is a group
>   of IEEE standards that define the API, shell, and utility interfaces
>   for an operating system. Although aimed at UNIX-like systems, the
>   standards can apply to any compatible operating system. Now that these
>   stan- dards have gained acceptance, software developers are able to
>   develop applications that run on all conforming versions of UNIX,
>   Linux, and other operating systems.

From the book: A Practical Guide To Linux

Answer (score 5):

Posix is more as an OS, it is an "OS standard". You can imagine it as an imaginary OS, which actually doesn't exist, but it has a documentation. These papers are the "posix standard", defined by the IEEE, which is the big standard organization of the USA.
The OSes implementing this specification are "Posix-compliant".

Government regulations prefer Posix-compliant solutions in their investments, thus being Posix-compliant has a significant financial advantage, particularly for the big IT companies of the USA.

The reward for an OS being fully posix compliant, that it is a guarantee that it will compile and run all Posix-compliant applications seamlessly.

Linux is the most well-known one. OSX, Solaris, NetBSD and Windows NT play here as well. Free- and OpenBSD are only "nearly" Posix-compliant. The posix-compliance of the WinNT is only a pseudo-solution to avoid this government regulation above.

Answer (score 4):

POSIX stands for Portable Operating System Interface, and is an IEEE standard designed to facilitate application portability. POSIX is an attempt by a consortium of vendors to create a single standard version of UNIX.

Answer (score 3):

This standard provides a common basis for Unix-like operating systems. It specifies how the shell should work, what to expect from commands like ls and grep, and a number of C libraries that C authors can expect to have available.

For example, the pipes that command-line users use to string together commands are specified in detail here, which means C’s popen (pipe open) function is POSIX-standard, not ISO C-standard.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX, on the other hand, stands for "Portable Operating System Interface" POSIX is a set of standards that define the interface between an operating system and application software. POSIX is similar to the UNIX standard, and it is intended to ensure that software written for one POSIX-compliant operating system can run on other POSIX-compliant operating systems without modification.

The POSIX standard defines a set of system calls, libraries, and utilities that are commonly found in UNIX-based operating systems.

Many operating systems, including Linux, BSD, and macOS, are POSIX-compliant, which means they meet the requirements defined in the POSIX standard.

Answer (score 0):

Posix governs interoperability, portability, and in other areas such as the usage and mechanism of fork, permissions <strike>and filesystem standards such as /etc, /var, /usr and so on</strike> . Hence, when developers write a program under a Posix compliant system such as for example Linux, it is generally, not always, guaranteed to run on another posix compliant system such as IBM's AIX system or other commercial variants of Unix. Posix is a good thing to have as such it eases the software development for maximum portability which it strives for. Hope this answer makes sense.

Thanks to Jed Smith & Tinkertim for pointing out my error - my bad!!! :(

Comment: Filesystem standards are handled outside of POSIX.

Comment: You are confusing POSIX with things like the LSB (Linux Standard Base). Two (mostly) POSIX compliant operating systems would be FBSD and Linux, yet both have rather different file system organization and default library installations.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX defines set of standards for an operating system or a program.
The goal is to write new software that is compatible with UNIX-like systems.

For example a program runs on Linux is also can be compile and run on other UNIX-like systems like Solaris, HP-UX, and AIX etc..

The most popular examples are `GNU Bash` which is 100% POSIX compliance and `gawk` utility.

Answer (score 0):

A specification (blueprint) about how to make an OS compatible with late UNIX OS (may God bless him!). This is why macOS and GNU/Linux have very similar terminal command lines, GUI's, libraries, etc. Because they both were designed according to POSIX blueprint.

POSIX does not tell engineers and programmers how to code but what to code.

Answer (score 0):

In one sentence, it is set of standards consisting of libraries, macros, system call, threading functions, io handling functions, system related functions etc. that helps in increasing your code portablity, which will be mostly run in unix, linux environment.

Answer (score -2):

Some facts about POSIX that are not so bright.

**POSIX is also the system call interface or API, and it is nearly 30 years old.**

It was designed for *serialized data access to local storage*, using single computers with single CPUs.

Security was not a major concern in POSIX by design, leading to numerous race condition attacks over the years and forcing programmers to work around these limitations.

Serious bugs are still being discovered, bugs that could have been averted with a more secure POSIX API design.

POSIX expects users to issue one synchronous call at a time and wait for its results before issuing the next. Today's programmers expect to issue many asynchronous requests at a time to improve overall throughput.

This synchronous API is particularly bad for accessing remote and cloud objects, where high latency matters.

Comment: Synchronous kernel API does not need to mean single-threaded processes and serialized IO. It has also nothing to do to SMP machines. These are completely unrelated. (While I agree that the sync kernel API is suboptimal, but not so heavily as in your post seems.)