# Deleting a folder that contains symlinks

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell

If I `rm -rf` a folder that has soft links in it, will it try to follow those links and delete the corresponding folder, or will it simply unlink them?

I have a copy of my home directory with symbolic links in it, and I'm scared to `rm -rf` it in case it follows those links and blows up the corresponding folders...

Answer (score 23):

Generally speaking, `rm` doesn't "delete". It "unlinks". This means that references to a file are removed by `rm`. When the number of references reaches zero, the file will no longer be accessible and in time, the area of disk where it resides will be used for something else.

When you `rm` a directory, the stuff inside the directory is unlinked. Symbolic links are (sort of like) files with the name of their targets inside them and so they're just removed. To actually figure out what they're pointing to and then unlink the target is special work and so will not be done by a generic tool.

Answer (score 16):

No. rm -rf won't follow symbolic links - it will simply remove them.

```
% mkdir a                                                             
% touch a/foo
% mkdir b                                                               
% ln -s a b/a                                                           
% rm -rf b                                                              
%   ls a                                                                  
foo
```

Answer (score 2):

Here  is axample:

```
find a b

a
a/1
a/2
b

ll

drwxr-xr-x 2 ****** ****** 4.0K Feb  6 15:11 a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ****** ****** 1 Feb  6 15:13 b -> a
```

.

```
rm -rf b
```

gives

```
find a b

a
a/1
a/2
```

.

```
rm -rf b/
```

gives error:

```
rm: cannot remove `b/': Not a directory
```

Conclusion:

rm does not follow symlinks

Comment: Sorry to necro an old post, but this is wrong. Indeed, rm -r will delete only the symlink itself, however, rm -r b/ will delete all contents of a (and then produces the error you reported)! It hence leaves a and b, but will have deleted a/1 and a/2.

Answer (score 0):

**POSIX quote**

Since `rm -r` [is POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780599/what-is-the-meaning-of-posix/31865755#31865755) we can also look at what they have to say: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/rm.html

> The rm utility shall not traverse directories by following symbolic links into other parts of the hierarchy, but shall remove the links themselves.

The rationale section mentions a bit more:

> The rm utility removes symbolic links themselves, not the files they refer to, as a consequence of the dependence on the unlink() functionality, per the DESCRIPTION. When removing hierarchies with -r or -R, the prohibition on following symbolic links has to be made explicit.