# Difference between uint32_t and u_int32_t

Tags: c

What is the difference between `u_int32_t` and `uint32_t`?

Comment: The latter is defined in C99's header, `stdint.h`. The former is not. From http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/release-wranglers/2004-August/000925.html it looks like maybe the u_ forms were used in BSD Unix? Anyway, you should use `uint32_t` in your code.

Comment: @Conrad Why is this a comment and not an answer?

Comment: @Core Xii: *Shrug*. I had never heard of u_int32_t before responding, I'm not an authoritative source on this.

Answer (score 15):

`uint32_t` is a standard C99 type `u_int32_t` is used internally in some POSIX implementations.

Comment: [What is POSIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1780599/2023530) This link answers the question which occurred to me.

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, uint32_t is a standard C99 type.

Anyway, the takeaway is that if you're writing portable C code or C header files meant to be shared between different devices/architectures, you can use stdint.h.

Answer (score 1):

uint32_t is standard C99, while u_int32_t is used on certain Unix platforms.

Answer (score 0):

The variable type uint32_t is an unsigned 32-bit integer data type defined according to the so-called C99 standard. Not all compilers comply with the standard. And u_int32_t is used for some internally implementations.