# What is u_int32_t?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Datatypes used in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090737/datatypes-used-in-c)

Hi
I'm doing porting from Linux to Visual C ++. And I found quite a few errors.
What is u_int32_t ? 
I can't find it in Visual C ++? Is it only available in Linux? Which type should I use in Visual C++? 
Thanks in advance !!!

Kevin

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The C99 header `stdint.h` defines types that do not depend on architecture or compiler. The meaning of unsigned int can differ (e.g. 16bit wide on a 16bit system), but those types from `stdint.h` have a specific size.

Either the additional underscore accidentally slipped in there, or someone re-typed them for some library or whatever. If the latter one is the case, include some header of your own, in that header include `stdint.h` and make sure to `typedef uint32_t u_int32_t` after the include.

Answer (score 7):

These not-quite-standard names appear to have been introduced by BSD: http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/release-wranglers/2004-August/000923.html

Answer (score 2):

I am not fully sure about the exact type, but based on the name, it looks like an **unsigned 32 bit integer**. The corresponding type in Visual C++ would be **unsigned int**.

There are other Aliases for that, but this name would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

This is an `int` datatype that is unsigned guaranteed to be 32 bits. To use it you need to include the [stdint.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h).

I am not sure whether this is available directly in the latest version of VC++. The wikipedia page has links to various implementations that work with Microsoft compilers (e.g. [msinttypes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h)).

If you are sure that the default `unsigned int` type is always going to be 32 bits, you may be able to just substitute `unsigned int` in its place. But using an explicit 32 bit datatype is preferable.

Comment: VC++ 2010 (currently the latest version) does indeed provide `stdint.h`.  But `stdint.h` provides the standard name `uint32_t`, not `u_int32_t` as mentioned in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about `u_int32_t`, but `uint32_t` is a [standard type according to the 1999 version of the C standard](http://www.google.com/search?q=stdint), coming from `<stdint.h>`.

Visual C++ has made a choice not to adopt C99, so it is not supported there.  If you include `<windows.h>` you can just use `DWORD`, which will be the same size and also unsigned.

Comment: VC++ 2010 provides a `stdint.h` that provides these typedefs.

Comment: @Ben Voight - I didn't know that.  Cool.  +1.

Comment: I mean it provides the standard types (`int8_t`, `uint8_t` ... `uint32_t`).  It doesn't provide `u_int32_t`, sorry if my earlier comment suggested that it did.