# Should I use C types (uint8_t/.../uint64_t) or (u_int8_t/.../u_int64_t)?

Tags: c++, c

My GNU-Linux platform (debian stretch) has the C types `u_int8_t`, `u_int16_t`, `u_int32_t` and `u_int64_t` defined in the file `sys/types.h` while `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` are defined in `stdint.h`. I have found these types useful in the course of practicing X86-64 assembly language and interacting with C. Is there any reason why I should prefer one header file over the other (be it 'best practice', portability etc.)?. Is the answer any different for C++?

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5163960/6879826) to an answer for a related question suggests that these names [originated with BSD](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/release-wranglers/2004-August/000923.html).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`stdint.h` is standard C, which maps to `cstdint` in standard C++.

`sys/types.h` is not portable C.

Comment: Indeed nothing in `sys` is portable.  That's why it's `sys`.

Comment: what is `cstdint`?

Comment: @ryyker [cstdint header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint).

Comment: @JohnZwinck-- [`sys/types.h` is POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/types.h.html), but there are no `u_intN_t` types specified there.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642827/cstdint-vs-stdint-h).

Comment: Technically `int8_t` etc. are not required by compilers either. The `_least` ones are. They're likely to be there but they're not required by the C standard (I don't know about C++).