# How to extract the date of creation of a photo using R?

Tags: r

I have more than 800 pictures where I need to extract the date of *creation*. But if I use the `file.mtime` function, it's not working. It's just the date that I modified it. The funny thing is that iPhoto (a program on mac to manage photos) is able to detect the date of creation properly.

This is the code I was using.

```
my.path = "~/Desktop/cool_path_here"
vec.jpg = list.files(path = my.path)
lapply(paste(my.path,vec.jpg,sep = "/"),FUN =  file.mtime)
```

Is there a function that could extract the date of creation of the photo and not the one that is shown in the "get info" menu on mac.

e.g.: (yesterday was May 18th)

[image]

and in iPhoto (found March 16th):

[image]

R is finding:

```
2017-05-19 15:08:29
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `exif` package to [extract the metadata](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exif/exif.pdf):

```
library(exif)
read_exif(paste(my.path,vec.jpg[1], sep="/"))$origin_timestamp
```

is returning `"2017:03:16 08:47:48"` which is the what I was looking for!

Comment: It seems like the package name is (now) "exifr"

Answer (score 1):

As per `?file.info`, `mtime` is the modification time, `ctime` is the "last status change" time, and `atime` is the last "access" time. According to [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91197/how-to-find-creation-date-of-file), the POSIX standard ([which Mac OS follows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785516/is-osx-a-posix-os)) does not include a creation time among the standard properties of a file.

`file.info(my.path)$atime` may be better. That didn't change in this test:

```
DF = data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 10:1)
tmp = tempfile()
write.table(DF, tmp)
Sys.time()
# [1] "2017-05-19 15:03:46 EDT"
file.info(tmp)[ , c('mtime', 'ctime', 'atime')]
#                                                mtime               ctime               atime
# /tmp/Rtmpzpi8p6/file29e932565c62 2017-05-19 15:03:46 2017-05-19 15:03:46 2017-05-19 15:03:46
DF$c = 11:20
Sys.sleep(10)
write.table(DF, tmp)
file.info(tmp)[ , c('mtime', 'ctime', 'atime')]
#                                                mtime               ctime               atime
# /tmp/Rtmpzpi8p6/file29e932565c62 2017-05-19 15:03:56 2017-05-19 15:03:56 2017-05-19 15:03:4
```

BTW, use the `full.names` argument to `list.files` instead of using `paste` and `sep='/'`.

Comment: I've tried this, but it's not working. I meant, there is other metadata in the jpeg that this function is not able to extract. I wonder if there is a way to extract that metadata in R. iPhoto is able to do it, so I guess R should be...

Comment: @M.Beausoleil you'll have to provide some reproducible example

Comment: I'd like to but can't really share the pictures in question. But for sure, there is an information that file.info is not getting and that iPhoto is able to reach.

Comment: @M.Beausoleil you don't necessarily need to share the pictures in question. Just mock up some files that you _can_ share, or even use Google.

Comment: @M.Beausoleil does this package work? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exif/exif.pdf

Comment: Yes, it's doing what I'm looking for, and it extracts a lot more information.  See my answer.