# How does Ctrl-C terminate a child process?

Tags: bash, shell, process, sh

I am trying to understand how <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> terminates a child but not a parent process. I see this behavior in some script shells like `bash` where you can start some long-running process and then terminate it by entering <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and the control returns to the shell.

Could you explain how does it work and in particular why isn't the parent (shell) process terminated?

Does the shell have to do some special handling of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> event and if yes what exactly does it do?

Comment: Why would terminating a child terminate the parent? And no, no special handling is needed.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: I am not asking why terminating a child is not terminating a parent. The question is more why does the child process get the Ctrl-C event and not the parent?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Signals by default are handled by the kernel. Old Unix systems had 15 signals; now they have more. You can check `</usr/include/signal.h>` (or kill -l). <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is the signal with name `SIGINT`.

The default action for handling each signal is defined in the kernel too, and usually it terminates the process that received the signal.

All signals (but `SIGKILL`) can be handled by program.

And this is what the shell does:

- When the shell running in interactive mode, it has a special signal handling for this mode.
- When you run a program, for example `find`, the shell:

  - `fork`s itself
  - and for the child set the default signal handling
  - replace the child with the given command (e.g. with find)
  - when you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, parent shell handle this signal but the child will receive it - with the default action - terminate. (the child can implement signal handling too)

You can `trap` signals in your shell script too...

And you can set signal handling for your interactive shell too, try enter this at the top of you `~/.profile`. (Ensure than you're a already logged in and test it with **another** terminal - you can lock out yourself)

```
trap 'echo "Dont do this"' 2
```

Now, every time you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in your shell, it will print a message. Don't forget to remove the line!

If interested, you can check the plain old `/bin/sh` signal handling in the source code [here](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/sh/xec.c).

At the above there were some misinformations in the comments (now deleted), so if someone interested here is a very nice link - [how the signal handling works](http://linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for the link. "The TTY demystified" is one of the best introductions I've ever seen.

Comment: SIGSTOP is also uncatchable.

Comment: *when you press `CTRL+C`, parent shell handle this signal* – this is plain wrong as shell does not even receive this signal in this scenario; see @JdeBP's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6110213/95735).

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost in the last link in my answer (http://linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php) is everything explained in detail. Really good reading.

Comment: In *The TTY demystified* article you clearly see the shell is in different process group than both `cat` and `ls | sort` pipeline. That is why it does not receive SIGINT signal which is being sent only to terminal's foreground process group. To cite from JdeBP's answer – *The shell process itself is in yet another process group all of its own and so doesn't receive the signal when one of those process groups is in the foreground. It's that simple*

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost See man. It is pointless to wrangle in the comments. If you know how process groups works, you know also than setting the process groups is a job for the shell. JeBP's answer is (mostly) true. Saying mostly, because it is true only for POSIX shells with job control. The basic principe is remain: the shell "doing something" for the signal handling. It can manage this with setting the signal handler to ignore, or (as JdeBP says) could play with process groups.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost Please remember, here as many shells, and many systems - and not everything care and plays with process groups.This is rather complicated topic, and isn't possible (universally) to say: "everything is based on process groups" - because it isn't true. In the reality - both answers are true. Most of modern shells (like bash) his answer is true, for other shells (e.g. `ash` or plain-old system V shell - without job-controll) is true my answer - they manage it with signal handling. And, the signal-handling method is universal. Check yourself some shell-sources. Thats all.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost and finally, ask yourself how the SIGHUP is handled. (E.g. when you send something in to background and disconnects the controlling terminal. (e.g. the line discipline generating the SIGHUP signal). Who receive it? (you know - not only the foreground process group . ) :) :)

Comment: @jm666 What do you mean by "replace the child with the given command (e.g. with find)"? Do you mean `fork(); exec(find)`?

Comment: @jm666 *"when you press CTRL+C, parent shell handle this signal but the child will receive it - with the default action - terminate. (the child can implement signal handling too)"* If I understand you correctly, you mean the signal would sent to ***both*** the parent process ***and*** the child process. Am I right?

Comment: @John In the (modern shells+modern OS) no. See the comments. In the simple shell implementations thats the simplest way handling the SIGINT. As I already said, this is a very good reading http://linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php .

Comment: @john yes. first the shell _forks_ itself and then the child _exec_ the command, e.g. the child was replaced by the command (e.g.find).

Answer (score 29):

First, read [the Wikipedia article on the POSIX terminal interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_terminal_interface) all of the way through.

The `SIGINT` signal is generated by the terminal line discipline, and broadcast to all processes in the terminal's *foreground process group*.  Your shell has already created a new process group for the command (or command pipeline) that you ran, and told the terminal that that process group is its (the terminal's) foreground process group.  Every concurrent command pipeline has its own process group, and the *foreground* command pipeline is the one with the process group that the shell has programmed into the terminal as the terminal's foreground process group.  Switching "jobs" between foreground and background is (some details aside) a matter of the shell telling the terminal which process group is now the foreground one.

The shell process itself is in yet another process group all of its own and so doesn't receive the signal when one of those process groups is in the foreground.  It's that simple.

Answer (score 7):

The terminal sends the INT (interrupt) signal to the process that is currently attached to the terminal. The program then receives it, and could choose to ignore it, or quit.

No process is necessarily being forcibly closed (although by default, if you don't handle sigint, I believe the behaviour is to call `abort()`, but I'd need to look that up).

Of course, the running process is isolated from the shell that launched it.

If you *wanted* the parent shell to go, launch your program with `exec`:

```
exec ./myprogram
```

That way, the parent shell is replaced by the child process

Comment: Do I understand correctly that when I start some process from a shell it gets attached to the terminal and that's why it gets the INT signal?

Comment: Normally, yes. For foreground jobs in popular shell, yes. It would depend on the shell, and whether there even is a terminal.

Comment: @kobame: So you are saying that the signal is first sent to the shell which then passes it to the child process? Why then sending the SIGINT manually to the shell doesn't kill the child, e.g. 'kill -2 <shell-pid>' doesn't do anything to a child process while Ctrl-C kills it?

Answer (score 3):

**`setpgid` POSIX C process group minimal example**

It might be easier to understand with a minimal runnable example of the underlying API.

This illustrates how the signal does get sent to the child, if the child didn't change its process group with `setpgid`.

main.c

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <assert.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t is_child = 0;

void signal_handler(int sig) {
    char parent_str[] = "sigint parent\n";
    char child_str[] = "sigint child\n";
    signal(sig, signal_handler);
    if (sig == SIGINT) {
        if (is_child) {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, child_str, sizeof(child_str) - 1);
        } else {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, parent_str, sizeof(parent_str) - 1);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    pid_t pid, pgid;

    (void)argv;
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    signal(SIGUSR1, signal_handler);
    pid = fork();
    assert(pid != -1);
    if (pid == 0) {
        is_child = 1;
        if (argc > 1) {
            /* Change the pgid.
             * The new one is guaranteed to be different than the previous, which was equal to the parent's,
             * because `man setpgid` says:
             * > the child has its own unique process ID, and this PID does not match
             * > the ID of any existing process group (setpgid(2)) or session.
             */
            setpgid(0, 0);
        }
        printf("child pid, pgid = %ju, %ju\n", (uintmax_t)getpid(), (uintmax_t)getpgid(0));
        assert(kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1) == 0);
        while (1);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    /* Wait until the child sends a SIGUSR1. */
    pause();
    pgid = getpgid(0);
    printf("parent pid, pgid = %ju, %ju\n", (uintmax_t)getpid(), (uintmax_t)pgid);
    /* man kill explains that negative first argument means to send a signal to a process group. */
    kill(-pgid, SIGINT);
    while (1);
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/0dc030e6040b6a21ca854c6e8fa28b722646d15e/posix/interactive/setpgid.c).

Compile with:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -o setpgid setpgid.c
```

**Run without `setpgid`**

Without any CLI arguments, `setpgid` is not done:

```
./setpgid
```

Possible outcome:

```
child pid, pgid = 28250, 28249
parent pid, pgid = 28249, 28249
sigint parent
sigint child
```

and the program hangs.

As we can see, the pgid of both processes is the same, as it gets inherited across `fork`.

Then whenever you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it outputs again:

```
sigint parent
sigint child
```

This shows how:

- to send a signal to an entire process group with `kill(-pgid, SIGINT)`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on the terminal sends a kill to the entire process group by default

Quit the program by sending a different signal to both processes, e.g. SIGQUIT with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>.

**Run with `setpgid`**

If you run with an argument, e.g.:

```
./setpgid 1
```

then the child changes its pgid, and now only a single sigint gets printed every time from the parent only:

```
child pid, pgid = 16470, 16470
parent pid, pgid = 16469, 16469
sigint parent
```

And now, whenever you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> only the parent receives the signal as well:

```
sigint parent
```

You can still kill the parent as before with a SIGQUIT (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>) however the child now has a different PGID, and does not receive that signal! This can seen from:

```
ps aux | grep setpgid
```

You will have to kill it explicitly with:

```
kill -9 16470
```

This makes it clear why signal groups exist: otherwise we would get a bunch of processes left over to be cleaned manually all the time.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: In the signal handler, you have `write(STDOUT_FILENO, sigint_str, sizeof(sigint_str));` — but that writes a null byte to the output too.  It would be better to use `sizeof(sigint_str) - 1` to avoid writing the null byte.  In POSIX 2018, many of the `str*` and `mem*()` functions from `<string.h>` are finally marked 'signal safe', so it would now be possible to use `strlen()`, but since the string is a fixed size, `sizeof(sigint_str) - 1` makes perfect sense too (and a good compiler would probably optimize the `strlen()` away anyway).

Comment: I wonder if it would be better to set the signal handler before writing to standard output?  It reduces the window of vulnerability, which might be considerable if the process is writing to a pipe and the pipe buffer is full.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the comments. Added a `- 1` on the `sizeof` which was definitely bad. I had never thought about what happens if another signal arrives, I think `man signal` says further signals are blocked by default on Linux and BSD, but not POSIX guaranteed, which is why `sigaction` would be preferred.