# Why Linux always output "^C" upon pressing of Ctrl+C?

Tags: linux, bash, signals, sigint

I have been studying signals in Linux. And I've done a test program to capture SIGINT.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <iostream>
void signal_handler(int signal_no);
int main() {
  signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  std::cout << "I'm sleeping..." << std::endl;
  unsigned int one_ms = 1000;
  usleep(200* one_ms);
  }
  return 0;
}
void signal_handler(int signal_no) {
  if (signal_no == SIGINT)
    std::cout << "Oops, you pressed Ctrl+C!\n";
  return;
}
```

While the output looks like this:

```
I'm sleeping...
I'm sleeping...
^COops, you pressed Ctrl+C!
I'm sleeping...
I'm sleeping...
^COops, you pressed Ctrl+C!
I'm sleeping...
^COops, you pressed Ctrl+C!
I'm sleeping...
^COops, you pressed Ctrl+C!
I'm sleeping...
^COops, you pressed Ctrl+C!
I'm sleeping...
I'm sleeping...
I'm sleeping...
```

I understand that when pressing Ctrl+C, processes in foreground process group all receives a SIGINT(if no process chooses to ignore it).

So is it that the shell(bash) AND the instance of the above program both received the signal? Where does the "^C" before each "Oops" come from?

The OS is CentOS, and the shell is bash.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is the terminal (driver) that intercepts the ^C and translates it to a signal sent to the attached process (which is the shell) `stty intr ^B` would instruct the terminal driver to intercept a ^B instead. It is also the terminal driver that echoes the ^C back to the terminal.

The shell is just a process that sits at the other end of the line, and receives it's stdin from your terminal via the terminal driver (such as /dev/ttyX), and it's stdout (and stderr) are also attached to the same tty.

Note that (if echoing is enabled) the terminal sends the keystrokes to *both* the process (group) and back to the terminal. The stty command is just wrapper around the ioctl()s for the tty driver for the processes "controlling" tty.

UPDATE: to demonstrate that the shell is not involved, I created the following small program. It should be executed by its parent shell via `exec ./a.out` (it appears an interactive shell will fork a daughter shell, anyway) The program sets the key that generates the SIGINTR to ^B, switches echo off, and than waits for input from stdin.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

int thesignum = 0;
void handler(int signum);

void handler(int signum)
{ thesignum = signum;}

#define THE_KEY 2 /* ^B */

int main(void)
{
int rc;
struct termios mytermios;

rc = tcgetattr(0 , &mytermios);
printf("tcgetattr=%d\n", rc );

mytermios.c_cc[VINTR] = THE_KEY; /* set intr to ^B */
mytermios.c_lflag &= ~ECHO ; /* Dont echo */
rc = tcsetattr(0 , TCSANOW, &mytermios);
printf("tcsetattr(intr,%d) =%d\n", THE_KEY, rc );

printf("Setting handler()\n" );
signal(SIGINT, handler);

printf("entering pause()\n... type something followed by ^%c\n", '@'+THE_KEY );
rc = pause();
printf("Rc=%d: %d(%s), signum=%d\n", rc, errno , strerror(errno), thesignum );

// mytermios.c_cc[VINTR] = 3; /* reset intr to ^C */
mytermios.c_lflag |= ECHO ; /* Do echo */
rc = tcsetattr(0 , TCSANOW, &mytermios);
printf("tcsetattr(intr,%d) =%d\n", THE_KEY, rc );

return 0;
}
```

intr.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $$
exec ./a.out
echo I am back.
```

Comment: Funny thing is that the other answer (which is plain wrong) still gets upvotes, just because it contains links to the Right Books.

Comment: @WiSaGaN  How can the same answer be "almost right" (comment to me) and "plain wrong" (comment to OP). **Of course** device drivers are involved when communicating with a system via peripherals (how come you didn't mention the keyboard driver?) Providing more details doesn't make an "almost right" answer "plain wrong". If I went to the level of machine language and lookup tables, would that make your answer incorrect?  Hardly. I provided links to books so OP could look up more details as needed. OP felt my answer was helpful. Your current comment is contradictory and disingenuous at best.

Comment: The wrong thing is that *the shell is not involved*. The conversion from ^C to INTR takes place in the terminal driver. The shell is only a receptor (like any other process) The stty is not targeting the shell, but the tty.

Comment: BTW: the "almost right" was caused by politeness on my side. "of course divice drivers are involved" is a very fuzzy statement. I did not mention the keyboard driver because it is not involved in **generating the signal**, only in converting the scancodes to usable characters. There need not even be a keyboard; the tty could refer to a modem line, or even a pty via telnet (in which case the generation of the INTR would follow a totally different path, but still performed by the pty-driver) Since you refer to APUE: chapter 11 can be useful.

Comment: This article contains a very helpful introduction to TTY(terminal). http://linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php

Answer (score 5):

The shell echoes everything you type, so when you type `^C`, that too gets echoed (and in your case intercepted by your signal handler). The command `stty -echo` may or may not be useful to you depending on your needs/constraints, see the [man page for stty](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?stty) for more information.

Of course much more goes on at a lower level, *anytime* you communicate with a system via peripherals device drivers (such as the keyboard driver that you use to generate the ^C signal, and the terminal driver that displays everything) are involved. You can dig even deeper at the level of assembly/machine language, registers, lookup tables etc. If you want a more detailed, in-depth level of understanding the books below are a good place to start:

[The Design of the Unix OS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132017997) is a good reference for these sort of things. Two more classic references: [Unix Programming Environment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013937681X) 
and [Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321525949)

Nice summary here in this SO question [How does Ctrl-C terminate a child process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108953/how-does-ctrl-c-terminate-a-child-process)

"when youre run a program, for example `find`, the shell:

- the shell fork itself
- and for the child set the default signal handling
- replace the child with the given command (e.g. with find)
- when you press CTRL-C, parent shell handle this signal but the child will receive it - with the default action - terminate. (the child can implement signal handling too)"

Comment: Do you mean that bash here is in the foreground process group as well, so it received the signal sent by the kernel?

Comment: @WiSaGaN I mean is that you use the keyboard to communicate with your program, and the shell is in between you and the program (i.e., the *interface*) so it intercepts this action. What your signal handler does is determine the *subsequent* action that occurs after the `^C` is seen. So rather than terminate the program,  you can have it do something else, like print a message in your case.

Comment: So it's actually the shell sending the signal to foreground process group(kernel actually implements it). And so the underlying events are, the keyboard caught Ctrl+C pressed and signals the CPU. Then a hardware interrupt invoked the interrupt handler, which tells the shell Ctrl+C has pressed. Then a signal is sent by the shell. So the "Ctrl+C keystroke" to "SIGINT signal" transformation is made by the shell. Am I correct?

Comment: Almost right. It is the terminal (driver) that intercepts the ^C and translates it to a signal sent to the attached process (which is the shell) `stty intr ^B` would instruct the terminal driver to intercept a ^B instead. It is also the terminal driver that echoes the ^C back to the terminal.

Comment: Yes, the `stty` command really helps. Thank both of you for explanation!