# Terminating a shell function non-interactively

Tags: shell, zsh

Is there a way to terminate a shell function *non-interactively* without killing the shell that's running it?

I know that the shell can be told how to respond to a signal (e.g. `USR1`), but I can't figure out how the signal handler would terminate the function.

If necessary you may assume that the function to be terminate has been written in such a way that it is "terminable" (i.e. by declaring some suitable options).

(My immediate interest is in how to do this for `zsh`, but I'm also interested in knowing how to do it for `bash` and for `/bin/sh`.)

EDIT: In response to Rob Watt's suggestion:

```
% donothing () { echo $$; sleep 1000000 }
% donothing
47139
```

If at this point I hit `Ctrl-C` at the same terminal that is running the shell, then the function `donothing` does indeed terminate, and I get the command prompt back.  But if instead, from a different shell session, I run

```
% kill -s INT 47139
```

...the `donothing` function does *not* terminate.

Comment: Do you mean something like control-c?

Comment: google e.g. "bash signal handling" and first match descripes signal handling for the bash-shell with a lot of examples using `trap`

Comment: @RobWatts: I've edited my post to account for your suggestion.

Comment: @FredrikPihl: I don't see an answer to my question among the examples in that page.  They all show how to terminate a script, not how to terminate a function.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you said how you are planning to use it? You might be able to accomplish your goal in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not fully understand what you want, but maybe something like this?

```
trap "stopme=1" 2

function longcycle() {
    last=$1
    for i in 1 2 3 4 5 
    do
        [ ! -z "$stopme" ] && return
        echo $i
        sleep 1
    done
}

stopme=""
echo "Start 1st cycle"
longcycle
echo "1st cycle end"

echo "2nd cycle"
stopme=""
longcycle
echo "2nd cycle end"
```

The above is for bash. Run it, and try press CTRL-C.

Or for `not interactively`, Save the above as for example `my_command`, then try:

```
$ ./my_command &  #into background
$ kill -2 $! #send CTRL-C to the bg process
```

EDIT:

Solution for your `sleep` example in the bash:

```
$ donothing() { trap '[[ $mypid ]] && trap - 2 && kill $mypid' 0 2; sleep 1000000 & mypid=$!;wait; }
$ donothing
```

when you send a signal from another terminal will terminate it. Remeber, signal '0' je "normal end of the process". Semantic name: 0=EXIT, 2=INT... etc.

and remeber too, than signals are sending **to processes** not to the functions. In your example, the process is the current (interactive shell), so must use the wait trick to get something interrupt-able... Not a nice solution - but the only way when want interrupt something what is running in interactive shell (not a forked one) from the another terminal...

Comment: why can't I replicate the effect of hitting `Ctrl-C` at the original terminal with a suitable `kill` command?

Comment: Because how signals works. Shell has special signal handling. When you run a command, the shell forks itself and restore default signal handling, e.g. when you send SIGINT tto the forked process, the process will terminate. But when you running a shell function ON YOUR TERMINAL shell directly (not a forked one) - the shell has special signal handling, e.g. when you press CTRL-C in the keyboard the shell trapping it and handle it in it own way.

Comment: check my answer to one other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108953/how-does-ctrl-c-terminate-a-child-process/6109189#6109189