# Terminate Python program on Ctrl+C when it's running a subprocess

Tags: sqlite, subprocess, python-2.x

I have a little program written in Python (version 2.7.3 on Linux) that runs an external command on a number of files in a loop. It does this using `subprocess.check_output` and it then writes data from the output into a Sqlite3 database. I have 2 problems:

1. When I hit `Ctrl+C` to stop the program, all that happens is the executing subprocess is killed and the main program just continues with the next iteration and launches the next subprocess.
2. If I force-kill it with a `kill -9` from another window it does exit but the databse file does not contain any changes.

I have been reading for several hours and trying various things including signal handlers, `try`/`finally` and so-on. I have so far been unable to do what ought to be very simple.

So, how can I have a Python program accept a `Ctrl+C` and cleanly terminate so that its subprocess ends and its sqlite3 database is correctly saved?

(just adding that, if the program is left to run to completion, it does exit cleanly and the database file is updated as expected)

Comment: I added a manual commit to the program and now at least the database is up to date after killing the program. Now I just need to work out how to cleanly handle a `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: your [parent process should die with `KeyboardInterrupt` exception](https://gist.github.com/e2804f0934b505946b99). Could you provide a complete minimal code example that shows the problem?

Comment: sorry for delay in responding. I stripped the programme to the basics and it doesn't exhibit the problem so I am going to do some more investigating here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good discussion/resources on understanding killing child processes here: [How does Ctrl-C terminate a child process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108953/how-does-ctrl-c-terminate-a-child-process)

The sql issue(without more info) sounds like you're interrupting the process from committing the data when you kill the process immaturely

Comment: what I actually want to do here is kill the parent process (i.e. the Python program). If I am in a terminal and I execute the Python program in the foreground, I would like to be able to enter `Ctrl+C` and have the Python program terminate. What happens now is that only its child process is terminated. I expect I need some code in the Python program but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, you can check for `Ctrl-C` using try/except:

```
try:
    #code here...
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    #cleanup code...
```

I do this all the time during development so that I can cleanly stop if I find something wrong.