# Why does subprocess not return anything when pinging a server on python?

Tags: python, subprocess, ping

I am using subprosess to ping a server, but I want to receive the full response. In the past I have used `os` to ping but this only returned `1` or `0`.

The code that I am using is:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '8.8.8.8'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out
```

I would like if if the response that I would see if I had ran it from the terminal was visible. Please note that I am using `-c` and not `-n` because I am using linux as the OS.

I am confused as to why this does't work because when I ran similar code, it printed out the expected response:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out
```

The code above printed out the list of files and folders in the directory which the python script was saved in, so the code that I am using seems to be correct.

My question is, how can I have the response from pinging a server assigned to a variable that I can then print out like I can when I run `ls`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `ping` is a continuous process; it doesn't stop until you interrupt it, e.g. with ctrl-C. Of course, with `subprocess`, ctrl-C is not possible.

[`subprocess.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) will buffer all the output in memory until the program ends (that is, never); you could use it in fact to create an out-of-memory error ;-).

If you just like a few pings, or even 1 ping, use the `-c` option to `ping`:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c1', '8.8.8.8'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

If you'd like continuous polling, you could wrap this in a `while` loop inside Python.

Comment: it is incorrect. It is possible to [emulate Ctrl+C with subprocess](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28387508/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Neat; though I guess it's not directly the most obvious way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

[`.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) waits for the child process to finish. `ping` with the given arguments does not exit unless you explicitly stop it e.g., [send it Ctrl+C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27995163/4279).

Here're varous methods to [stop reading process output in Python without hang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4418891/4279).

If want to see the output while the process is still running; see [Python: read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279)