# Output result of a ping with subprocess.call to a text file

Tags: python, variables, subprocess, ping

I'm attempting to ping an IP address in Windows with Python. I want to output the result of the ping into a text file, but I don't know how to do that with the subprocess.call function. I know how to write variables to a file, but I don't know how to assign anything from the subprocess.call to a variable.

For example, if I pinged, I would want the text file to look like this

```
Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

How would I do this?

Comment: How dou you call ping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `ping` in a reasonable shell (for instance `cmd.exe`), you can use I/O redirection:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 > file
```

`>` means the output of the program is written to the given file.

If you call it as a python subprocess (not easy to derive from your question), you can use `Popen`:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    process = subprocess.Popen('ping 127.0.0.1', stdout=output)
    process.communicate()
```

Comment: *subprocess.check_output* will be even simpler

Comment: Yes, I'm calling it as a Python subprocess. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @volcano: no. `check_output()` is *not* appropriate here.

Comment: @Darkshadows: you don't need `.communicate()` here. You could use `subprocess.check_call(['ping', '127.0.0.1'], stdout=output)` instead. If you need to interrupt `ping` process; see [ping for indefinite amount of time and get its output in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27994854/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, care to explain why _check_output()_ is not appropriate?

Comment: OP wants to redirect the output to a file. `check_output()` returns the output as a string.