# Python subprocess signal

Tags: python, subprocess, signals

I would like to establish a very simple communication between two python scripts. I have decided that the best way to communicate and to have both scripts read from a text file. I would like the main program to wait while to child programs execute.

Normally I would make the main program wait x amount of time and continuously check the text file for an okay flag. However I have seen people talk about using a signal.

Could someone please give an example of this.

Comment: http://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/ provides an example of using signal. Look at the Signaling Between Processes subsection.

Comment: 1. Why do you use `subprocess` instead of importing the corresponding modules and calling the necessary function directly (possibly using `threading`, `multiprocessing` modules)? 2. There are many IPC methods and the reading from a text file on receiving a signal might not be the best option e.g., you could use pipes to exchange data between processes instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is [`Popen.send_signal()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.send_signal) that allows you to send a signal to a child process.

Here's [code example that sends `SIGINT` to `ping` subprocess to get the summary in the output on exit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27995163/4279).

Answer (score -1):

You need one process to write and one to read; both processes reading leads to no communication. Signals are used only for special proposes, not for normal inter-process-communication. Use something like pipes or sockets. It's not more complicated than files, but much more powerful.