# How to overcome going futher down in git Bash

Tags: git, git-bash

I just went to commit using git bash. Before type anything accidentally typed character ' and press Enter key.

Unfortunately, I can not exit the editor it keeps going further down when I typed something and press Enter. I tried Exit, Clear everything.

Anyone can help me please.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Type another `'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can type Ctrl + C to kill the process. Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108953/how-does-ctrl-c-terminate-a-child-process) link to see how it works

> Ctrl+C is a map to the kill command. When you press them, kill sends a
>   SIGINT signal, that's interrupts the process.

You can also type another `'` to "fix" your issue. Read [this](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting) link to understand how quoting is treated in bash

> **Strong quoting**
>
> Strong quoting is very easy to explain:
>
> Inside a single-quoted string nothing(!!!!) is interpreted, except the
>   single-quote that closes the quoting.
>
> echo 'Your PATH is: $PATH' That $PATH won't be expanded, it's
>   interpreted as normal ordinary text, because it's surrounded by strong
>   quotes.   In practise that means, to produce a text like Here's my
>   test… as a single-quoted string, you have to leave and re-enter the
>   single-quoting to get the character "'" as literal text:  # WRONG echo
>   'Here's my test...'
>
> RIGHT echo 'Here'\''s my test...'
>
> ALTERNATIVE: It's also possible to mix-and-match quotes for readability: echo "Here's my test"