# docker-compose env_file available in script but not directy in run command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is my set up:

docker-compose.yml:

```
php:
  container_name: php
  image: pawlik/kinetic-php:5.5
  env_file:
    - .env.defaults
```

.env.defaults:

```
STORE_URL_SECURE=https://kinetic.docker.dev/
```

In the running image I have such simple script:

showvars.sh

```
echo $STORE_URL_SECURE
```

Now running:

```
$ docker-compose run php bash showvars.sh
Starting data
https://kinetic.docker.dev/
```

looks great, but

```
$ docker-compose run php echo $STORE_URL_SECURE
Starting data

# empty!
```

What is the difference? Why in the second example this ENV var is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker-compose run php echo $STORE_URL_SECURE` means the shell which executes the docker-compose command also interpret `$STORE_URL_SECURE` (which is not defined or set in that shell session).
Hence `# empty!`.

However, this would work:

```
 docker-compose run php /bin/sh -c 'echo $STORE_URL_SECURE'
```

(with the [strong quotes or simple quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445202/6309) preventing the shell to interpret `$STORE_URL_SECURE` right away)

Comment: Ah! Now so obvious. Thx!