# Will ctrl+c send SIGINT signals to both parent and child processes in Linux?

Tags: linux, signals, fork

In the terminal, I executed a main parent process which will fork a child process. In both the parent and child processes I implemented a SIGINT signal handler. 
So when I press "ctrl+c", will both the handlers be called at the same time? Or do I need to call the child process's signal handler explicitly in the parent process's handler?

I looked up this post: 
[How does Ctrl-C terminate a child process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108953/how-does-ctrl-c-terminate-a-child-process)
which says that "*The SIGINT signal is generated by the terminal line discipline, and broadcast to all processes in the terminal's **foreground** process group*". I just didn't quite understand what does "foreground process group" means.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Ctrl-C terminate a child process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108953/how-does-ctrl-c-terminate-a-child-process)

Comment: You cannot "call" a routine in a different process; you could only "send a signal".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> In both the parent and child processes I implemented a SIGINT signal
>   handler. So when I press "ctrl+c", will both the handlers be called at
>   the same time?

Yes, they both will receive `SIGINT`.

> Or do I need to call the child process's signal handler explicitly in
>   the parent process's handler?

"Calling" another process' signal handler doesn't make sense. If the both the process have a handler installed then they will be called once they receive the signal `SIGINT`.

> I just didn't quite understand what does "foreground process group"
>   means.

Typically, a process associated with a controlling terminal is foreground process and its process group is called *foreground process group.* When you start a process from the command line, it's a foreground process:

E.g.

```
$ ./script.sh # foreground process
$ ./script & # background process
```

I suggest you read about [`tty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html) and [`The TTY demystified`](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4):

**`setpgid` POSIX C process group minimal example**

This illustrates how the signal does get sent to the child, if the child didn't change its process group with `setpgid`.

main.c

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <assert.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t is_child = 0;

void signal_handler(int sig) {
    char parent_str[] = "sigint parent\n";
    char child_str[] = "sigint child\n";
    signal(sig, signal_handler);
    if (sig == SIGINT) {
        if (is_child) {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, child_str, sizeof(child_str) - 1);
        } else {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, parent_str, sizeof(parent_str) - 1);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    pid_t pid, pgid;

    (void)argv;
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    signal(SIGUSR1, signal_handler);
    pid = fork();
    assert(pid != -1);
    if (pid == 0) {
        /* Change the pgid.
         * The new one is guaranteed to be different than the previous, which was equal to the parent's,
         * because `man setpgid` says:
         * > the child has its own unique process ID, and this PID does not match
         * > the ID of any existing process group (setpgid(2)) or session.
         */
        is_child = 1;
        if (argc > 1) {
            setpgid(0, 0);
        }
        printf("child pid, pgid = %ju, %ju\n", (uintmax_t)getpid(), (uintmax_t)getpgid(0));
        assert(kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1) == 0);
        while (1);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    /* Wait until the child sends a SIGUSR1. */
    pause();
    pgid = getpgid(0);
    printf("parent pid, pgid = %ju, %ju\n", (uintmax_t)getpid(), (uintmax_t)pgid);
    /* man kill explains that negative first argument means to send a signal to a process group. */
    kill(-pgid, SIGINT);
    while (1);
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/0dc030e6040b6a21ca854c6e8fa28b722646d15e/posix/interactive/setpgid.c).

Compile with:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -o setpgid setpgid.c
```

**Run without `setpgid`**

Without any CLI arguments, `setpgid` is not done:

```
./setpgid
```

Possible outcome:

```
child pid, pgid = 28250, 28249
parent pid, pgid = 28249, 28249
sigint parent
sigint child
```

and the program hangs.

As we can see, the pgid of both processes is the same, as it gets inherited across `fork`.

Then whenever you hit:

```
Ctrl + C
```

It outputs again:

```
sigint parent
sigint child
```

This shows how:

- to send a signal to an entire process group with `kill(-pgid, SIGINT)`
- Ctrl + C on the terminal sends a kill to the entire process group by default

Quit the program by sending a different signal to both processes, e.g. SIGQUIT with `Ctrl + \`.

**Run with `setpgid`**

If you run with an argument, e.g.:

```
./setpgid 1
```

then the child changes its pgid, and now only a single sigint gets printed every time from the parent only:

```
child pid, pgid = 16470, 16470
parent pid, pgid = 16469, 16469
sigint parent
```

And now, whenever you hit:

```
Ctrl + C
```

only the parent receives the signal as well:

```
sigint parent
```

You can still kill the parent as before with a SIGQUIT:

```
Ctrl + \
```

however the child now has a different PGID, and does not receive that signal! This can seen from:

```
ps aux | grep setpgid
```

You will have to kill it explicitly with:

```
kill -9 16470
```

This makes it clear why signal groups exist: otherwise we would get a bunch of processes left over to be cleaned manually all the time.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.