# Start and stop a node application using command prompt.

Tags: node.js

I have created a node application and run it in 3000 port. Now I need to stop/start/restart this application by using command prompt.  How can I do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get started with Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js)

Comment: Possibly related: [node.js as a background service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/node-js-as-a-background-service)

Comment: In general... Start: execute `node entryScript.js` – Stop: [`[Ctrl]+[c]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108953/how-does-ctrl-c-terminate-a-child-process)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using linux
If you need to stop some application running on some specific port use this and you know the port but not the process id. find the process id like this

```
netstat -plten | grep LISTEN | grep 3000
```

this will output some thing like this

```
tcp        0      0 :::10060                    :::*                          LISTEN      0          20465      3489/node
```

where 3489 is the process id.

then do

```
kill -9 3489
```

to kill the procees

Comment: No I am using Windows

Comment: okk Then do this  netstat -aon | find /i "3000" and then the answer is    TCP    0.0.0.0:3000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       9348
TCP    [::]:3000              [::]:0                 LISTENING       9348                               Then do Taskkill /PID 9348 /F

Comment: Thanks it works for me. How to kill all node process using this taskkill command

Comment: I think taskkill /F /IM node.exe

Comment: write tasklist in the cmd and check if any node program is running or not. And this will give you all the pid of the processes so you can kill them one by one also

Comment: The tasklist command is showing all running tasks. How to know which are node app processes.

Comment: all the node processes should be defined by node.exe in the left most collumn. and I think you do not have any node process running on your system as taskkill /F /IM node.exe command is saying process node.exe not found

Answer (score 5):

Start:`node app.js`

Stop:`Ctrl + C`

Restart:`node app.js`

Better option try Nodemon. Nodemon is a utility that will monitor for any changes in your source and automatically restart your server.

1. Install nodemon globally `npm install nodemon -g`
2. Run the server `nodemon app.js`

Comment: yes but in my server multiple node application is running. How I can stop a particular app running on 3000 port

Answer (score 1):

You can simply press 'Ctrl + C' to stop any process in cmd. Also consider using [nodemon](http://nodemon.io/) , its a fantastic tool which automatically restarts your app whenever you save any new changes to the files.