# Mac restarts instead of rails server restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line, terminal.app

I am new to rails and so am still learning the ins and outs of the language.

When restarting my rails server, my Mac restarts instead of the server.

I first enter in Terminal `sudo su` to log into **root**, and then enter `reboot` which is what I am told is the command to restart the server.

So after I have logged in, what is the command to restart the rails server?

Comment: As you found out, `reboot` by itself is the command to restart a computer. =)

Comment: @Ryan What would be the command to reboot the server then?

Comment: See the linked duplicate.

Comment: @Ryan I did, but the link on that question of which the answer correlates to has expired.

Comment: Doesn’t matter, you still use Ctrl+C.

Comment: @Ryan Even if I am using Mac?

Comment: Yes. The duplicate is about Macs. When you run `rails start`, the last line that shows up is “Use Ctrl-C to stop”, right?

Comment: Remember that you're running the server from the command line, so you want to interrupt the process with Ctrl-C. If you're interested in understanding the why and how of this more clearly, checkout this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108953/how-does-ctrl-c-terminate-a-child-process