# Running multiple commands in parallel and exiting cleanly

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing

In this example I have three commands running in parallel.

```
sleep 1 && echo 'one' &
sleep 2 && echo 'two'&
sleep 1 && echo 'three'&
sleep 2 && echo 'four' & 
wait

echo "done"
```

When I exit / quit the command with a keyboard shortcut the command still seems to be outputting.

```
➜  example: ✗ sh ./scripts.sh
three
one
two
four
done
➜  example: ✗ sh ./scripts.sh
^C%➜  example: ✗ one
three
two
four
```

How can I cleanly exit?

Comment: the goal is to stop all background jobs OR only the last 4 jobs?

Comment: Hey @RomanPerekhrest, The goal is to stop all background jobs.

Answer (score 1):

By default signals handled by Kernal, but i have seen reference saying all signals except `kill` can be handled by program also,we can capture `CNTRL + C` signal using trap like below for instance,

```
finish(){
    < code to kill child process goes here >
}
trap finish EXIT

sleep 1 && echo 'one' &
sleep 2 && echo 'two' &
sleep 1 && echo 'three'&
sleep 2 && echo 'four' &

wait
```

for more , [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108953/how-does-ctrl-c-terminate-a-child-process) or [redsymbol.net](http://redsymbol.net/articles/bash-exit-traps/)

Answer (score 0):

With @JithinScarla's help and this other [stackoverflow post I made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717516/collecting-process-ids-of-parallel-process-in-bash-file?noredirect=1#comment82397514_47717516) I put this together which seems to get the job done.

```
process_ids=( )

finish(){
    for i in "${process_ids[@]}"; do
        kill -9 $i > /dev/null 2> /dev/null || :
    done
}

append() { process_ids+=( "$1" ); }       # POSIX-standard function declaration syntax

{ sleep 1 && echo 'one'; } & append $!
{ sleep 5 && echo 'two'; } & append $!
{ sleep 1 && echo 'three'; } & append $!
{ sleep 5 && echo 'four'; } & append $!

echo "Background processes:"              # Demonstrate that our array was populated
printf ' - %s\n' "${process_ids[@]}"

trap finish EXIT

wait
```

Or here even a bit cleaner:

```
function runParallel {
    process_ids=( )
    finish(){
        for i in "${process_ids[@]}"; do
            kill -9 $i > /dev/null 2> /dev/null || :
        done
    }
    append() { process_ids+=( "$1" ); }       # POSIX-standard function declaration syntax
    processes=( "$@" )
    for i in "${processes[@]}"; do
        { eval $i; } & append $!
    done
    trap finish EXIT
    wait
}

runParallel \
    "sleep 1 && echo 'one'" \
    "sleep 5 && echo 'two'" \
    "sleep 1 && echo 'three'" \
    "sleep 5 && echo 'four'"
```