# signal propagation from boost::process to boost::child

Tags: c++, linux, signals, boost-process

I am using `boost::process` v. 1.65.1 in a master application for Linux to create few `boost::process::child` objects and manage data exchanged via `boost::process::std_in` and `boost::process::std_out` i.e. pipes.

When my master application receives a CTRL-C sent by console, I see that the child as well do receive  a CTRL-C signal.

To terminate my child I'd prefer to send a clear command via pipe, but when I do this the signal has been propagated already. Actually Some child sees the command other do not and see the signal.

1. Is this signal propagation the normal behavior?
2. What I can do to prevent this to happen so that I can issue my command via pipe without interference?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this signal propagation the normal behavior?

It's not propagation per se, it's that when you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in a POSIX terminal, the `SIGINT` signal is broadcast to *all processes* of the terminal's *foreground process group*. Process groups are managed by the shell and by default forked processed remain in the group of the parent ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108953/how-does-ctrl-c-terminate-a-child-process)).

> What I can do to prevent this to happen so that I can issue my command via pipe without interference?

Intercept `SIGINT` in the child and perform the necessary cleanup:

```
#include <boost/asio/signal_set.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void exit_handler(const boost::system::error_code&, int signal_number)
{
  std::cerr << "Signal " << signal_number << "!\n";
  exit(1);
}

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  boost::asio::signal_set signals(io_service, SIGINT);

  signals.async_wait( exit_handler );

  io_service.run();
}
```

It's probably a good idea to think about other signals as well (`HUP`, `TERM`).

Comment: thanks for your response. In true  I have 2 issue. The first is that. I want my app to exit on a command received via pipe, so probably in that signal handler I should not call std::exit. The second one, which is the bigger, is the that I am using linux 'poll' to read from console. If I do like you say the 'polling', which is supposed to read the STOP command, returns on signal and doesn't do the read.  What can I do for this case? Do you think that signal masking could be an option? I never used them but I understood that prevents the signal to be completely ignored.

Comment: @rustyx does that apply to windows CMD as well? Because I observe the behavior similar to that in the question on Windows as well