# KeyboardInterrupt with Python multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, sigint, keyboardinterrupt

I want to write a service that launches multiple workers that work infinitely and then quit when main process is Ctrl+C'd. However, I do not understand how to handle Ctrl+C correctly.

I have a following testing code:

```py
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
    

def g():
    print(os.getpid())
    while True:
        pass
        
        
def main():
    with mp.Pool(1) as pool:
        try:
            s = pool.starmap(g, [[]] * 1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('Done')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(os.getpid())
    main()
```

When I try to Ctrl+C it, I expect process(es) running `g` to just receive `SIGTERM` and silently terminate, however, I receive something like that instead:

```
Process ForkPoolWorker-1:
Done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 51, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
  File "test.py", line 8, in g
    pass
KeyboardInterrupt
```

This obviously means that parent and children processes both raise `KeyboardInterrupt` from Ctrl+C, further suggested by tests with `kill -2`. Why does this happen and how to deal with it to achieve what I want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard Interrupts with python's multiprocessing Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408356/keyboard-interrupts-with-pythons-multiprocessing-pool)

Comment: @Charchit No, the question you linked is concerned with a bug in old python version which has been fixed since then, mine is not related to that.

Comment: The **accepted** answer talks about the bug, the other answers are more recent and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6191991/16310741) (on the same thread) basically says the same thing as the accepted answer here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signal that triggers `KeyboardInterrupt` is delivered to the whole pool. The child worker processes treat it the same as the parent, raising `KeyboardInterrupt`.

The easiest solution here is:

1. Disable the `SIGINT` handling in each worker on creation
2. Ensure the parent terminates the workers when it catches `KeyboardInterrupt`

You can do this easily by passing an `initializer` function that the `Pool` runs in each worker before the worker begins doing work:

```
import signal
import multiprocessing as mp

# Use initializer to ignore SIGINT in child processes
with mp.Pool(1, initializer=signal.signal, initargs=(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)) as pool:
    try:
        s = pool.starmap(g, [[]] * 1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Done')
```

The `initializer` replaces the default `SIGINT` handler with one that ignores `SIGINT` in the children, leaving it up to the parent process to kill them. The `with` statement in the parent handles this automatically (exiting the `with` block implicitly calls `pool.terminate()`), so all you're responsible for is catching the `KeyboardInterrupt` in the parent and converting from ugly traceback to simple message.

Comment: Using initializer for ignoring `SIGINT` is elegant, I will likely use it. But why is it delivered to the whole pool? When I tested it with `kill -2 <parent pid>`, it simply behaved as I expected, only sending it to parent and printing `Done`. Is this `bash` behavior?

Comment: @steam_engine: [Per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6110213/364696), "The `SIGINT` signal is generated by the terminal line discipline, and broadcast to all processes in the terminal's *foreground process group*. Your shell has already created a new process group for the command (or command pipeline) that you ran, and told the terminal that that process group is its (the terminal's) foreground process group." Basically, yes, hitting Ctrl-C, at least on POSIX, sends `SIGINT` to the entire foreground process group, not just the parent process.

Comment: Presumably `os.setpgrp()` could work too (untested, don't quote me), if the child process `initializer` used it to detach from the parent process group, but it's UNIX-only, so if you want consistent behavior across OSes, it's not viable.