# Why do you need ./ (dot-slash) before executable or script name to run it in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line

When running scripts in bash, I have to write `./` in the beginning:

```
$ ./manage.py syncdb
```

If I don't, I get an error message:

```
$ manage.py syncdb
-bash: manage.py: command not found
```

What is the reason for this? I thought `.` is an alias for current folder, and therefore these two calls should be equivalent.

I also don't understand why I don't need `./` when running applications, such as:

```
user:/home/user$ cd /usr/bin
user:/usr/bin$ git
```

(which runs without `./`)

Comment: This is the best document on the matter that I've come across so far: http://www.linfo.org/dot_slash.html

Comment: another explanation about `./` in [unix exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397524/what-does-the-mean-dot-slash-in-linux) and [unix exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-dot-slash-to-execute-a-file-in-linux-unix)

Answer (score 353, accepted):

Because on Unix, usually, the current directory is not in `$PATH`.

When you type a command the shell looks up a list of directories, as specified by the `PATH` variable. The current directory is not in that list.

The reason for not having the current directory on that list is security.

Let's say you're root and go into another user's directory and type `sl` instead of `ls`. If the current directory is in `PATH`, the shell will try to execute the `sl` program in that directory (since there is no other `sl` program). That `sl` program might be malicious.

It works with `./` because [POSIX specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01) that a command name that contain a `/` will be used as a filename directly, suppressing a search in `$PATH`. You could have used full path for the exact same effect, but `./` is shorter and easier to write.

**EDIT**

That `sl` part was just an example. The directories in `PATH` are searched sequentially and when a match is made that program is executed. So, depending on how `PATH` looks, typing a normal command may or may not be enough to run the program in the current directory.

Comment: You don't need to mistype anything. The user may just have downloaded a malicious package that contains an `ls` executable in it.

Comment: Does this mean that `.` is not just alias for current folder but actually ‘expands’ to the whole path? Didn't know that, thanks..

Comment: Just a note to everyone saying this is only in Unix and not Windows, this is the same in Powershell - you have to do `.\my.bat` etc to execute

Comment: @gaearon ergh, I said "is not an alias", when that should have been "is strictly an alias".

Comment: That was a very helpful explanation. 20+ years ago when I worked with DOS a little, I think CMD would check the current directory, an THEN the PATH, so Linux's behavior was not what I expected, but it makes a LOT of sense.

Comment: @cnicutar : Interestingly today I found that there is a `sl` command called steam locomotive although not available by default ;-)

Comment: I never mistype ls, but always install sl anyway. Steam locomotive FTW :D

Comment: If the sample `sl` program is in an other directory which is in PATH, then it is not malicious anymore?

Comment: If I recall correctly it used to be a very long time ago.  Then it was found that this is not a good default, and "." was removed from the default PATH.

Comment: I don't get it. How is this is a security measure, if it can easily be bypassed with `./`?

Comment: It's to prevent accidents. Explicitly typing `./` means that you specifically want to execute the file from the current directory. If there's a file called `ls` then you're telling the shell that you want to run that file, not the built in `ls` command. Otherwise, just happening to be in a directory with a file called `ls` would run that one.

Answer (score 56):

When bash interprets the command line, it looks for commands in locations described in the environment variable `$PATH`.  To see it type:

```
echo $PATH
```

You will have some paths separated by colons. As you will see the current path `.` is usually not in `$PATH`. So Bash cannot find your command if it is in the current directory. You can change it by having:

```
PATH=$PATH:.
```

This line adds the current directory in `$PATH` so you can do:

```
manage.py syncdb
```

It is **not** recommended as it has security issue, plus you can have weird behaviours, as `.` varies upon the directory you are in :)

Avoid:

```
PATH=.:$PATH
```

As you can “mask” some standard command and open the door to security breach :)

Just my two cents.

Answer (score 44):

Your script, when in your home directory will not be found when the shell looks at the `$PATH` environment variable to find your script.

The `./` says 'look in the current directory for my script rather than looking at all the directories specified in `$PATH`'.

Answer (score 5):

When you include the '.' you are essentially giving the "full path" to the executable bash script, so your shell does not need to check your PATH variable.  Without the '.' your shell will look in your PATH variable (which you can see by running `echo $PATH` to see if the command you typed lives in any of the folders on your PATH.  If it doesn't (as is the case with manage.py) it says it can't find the file.  It is considered bad practice to include the current directory on your PATH, which is explained reasonably well here: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part2/section-13.html

Answer (score 2):

On *nix, unlike Windows, the current directory is usually not in your `$PATH` variable. So the current directory is not searched when executing commands. You don't need `./` for running applications because these applications *are* in your $PATH; most likely they are in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

This question already has some awesome answers, but I wanted to add that, if your executable is on the PATH, and you get very different outputs when you run

```
./executable
```

to the ones you get if you run

```
executable
```

(let's say you run into error messages with the one and not the other), then the problem could be that you have two different versions of the executable on your machine: one on the path, and the other not.

Check this by running

which  executable

and

```
whereis executable
```

It fixed my issues...I had three versions of the executable, only one of which was compiled correctly for the environment.

Comment: `whereis` is not a standard command in most shells. The POSIX equivalent is `command -v` and/or `type`. There is also `which` which is quite prevalent, but non-standard and occasionally catastrophically wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**Rationale for the `/` POSIX PATH rule**

The rule was mentioned at: [Why do you need ./ (dot-slash) before executable or script name to run it in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331075/why-do-you-need-dot-slash-before-executable-or-script-name-to-run-it-in-bas/6331085#6331085) but I would like to explain why I think that is a good design in more detail.

First, an explicit full version of the rule is:

- if the path contains `/` (e.g. `./someprog`, `/bin/someprog`, `./bin/someprog`): CWD is used and PATH isn't
- if the path does not contain `/` (e.g. `someprog`): PATH is used and CWD isn't

Now, suppose that running:

```
someprog
```

would search:

- relative to CWD first
- relative to PATH after

Then, if you wanted to run `/bin/someprog` from your distro, and you did:

```
someprog
```

it would sometimes work, but others it would fail, because you might be in a directory that contains another unrelated `someprog` program.

Therefore, you would soon learn that this is not reliable, and you would end up always using absolute paths when you want to use PATH, therefore defeating the purpose of PATH.

This is also why having relative paths in your PATH is a really bad idea. I'm [looking at you, `node_modules/bin`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621132/why-is-using-the-execdir-action-insecure-for-directory-which-is-in-the-path).

Conversely, suppose that running:

```
./someprog
```

Would search:

- relative to PATH first
- relative to CWD after

Then, if you just downloaded a script `someprog` from a git repository and wanted to run it from CWD, you would never be sure that this is the actual program that would run, because maybe your distro has a:

```
/bin/someprog
```

which is in you PATH from some package you installed after drinking too much after Christmas last year.

Therefore, once again, you would be forced to always run local scripts relative to CWD with full paths to know what you are running:

```
"$(pwd)/someprog"
```

which would be extremely annoying as well.

Another rule that you might be tempted to come up with would be:

> relative paths use only PATH, absolute paths only CWD

but once again this forces users to always use absolute paths for non-PATH scripts with `"$(pwd)/someprog"`.

The `/` path search rule offers a simple to remember solution to the about problem:

- slash: don't use `PATH`
- no slash: only use `PATH`

which makes it super easy to always know what you are running, by relying on the fact that files in the current directory can be expressed either as `./somefile` or `somefile`, and so it gives special meaning to one of them.

Sometimes, is slightly annoying that you cannot search for `some/prog` relative to `PATH`, but I don't see a saner solution to this.

Comment: Don't name a program the same name as something on PATH unless you are recreating it...

Comment: @Eli I didn't suggest you should. But it is not possible to avoid completely since there is no global index of all executables that exist in all projects unfortunately.

Comment: That's fine, but your essay misses the better solution to allow without ./ to search first PATH and then CWD and ./ to first search CWD.

Answer (score -1):

When the script is not in the Path its required to do so. For more  info read http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_01.html

Comment: ...FYI, in #bash on irc.freenode.org, we're constantly correcting misunderstandings people have learned from TLDP (particularly the Advanced Bash Guide). As such, directing people there is... maybe not ideal. (Our preferred introductory documentation is http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide)

Answer (score -2):

All has great answer on the question, and yes this is only applicable when running it on the current directory not unless you include the absolute path. See my samples below.

Also, the (dot-slash) made sense to me when I've the command on the child folder tmp2 (/tmp/tmp2) and it uses (double dot-slash).

SAMPLE:

```
[fifiip-172-31-17-12 tmp]$ ./StackO.sh

Hello Stack Overflow

[fifi@ip-172-31-17-12 tmp]$ /tmp/StackO.sh

Hello Stack Overflow

[fifi@ip-172-31-17-12 tmp]$ mkdir tmp2

[fifi@ip-172-31-17-12 tmp]$ cd tmp2/

[fifi@ip-172-31-17-12 tmp2]$ ../StackO.sh

Hello Stack Overflow
```