# using gdb debug c

Tags: c, gdb, protocol-buffers

I run this command in my terminal,

```
gcc -g -I/usr/include -g sample_client.c lsp.o lspmessage.pb-c.o -o sample_client -L/usr/lib -lprotobuf-c
```

in my file directory, I can see a sample_client file. Its property is executable.
However, when I run

```
(gdb) sample_client
```

I got this,

```
Undefined command: "sample_client".
```

How can I debug?

Comment: Or `gdb` and then `run sample_client <args>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ gdb ./sample_client
(gdb) run
```

To pass command-line arguments to your program use `--args`:

```
$ gdb --args ./sample_client arg1 arg2 arg3
(gdb) run
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you please recommend some material with examples to learn gdb stuff. I am quite new to gdb.

Comment: @user2036452, note that the need to add `./` to executable name is not related to gdb, this is just the fact that unix shells do not add current directory to `$PATH` for [security reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6331085/693538), so when you type just `sample_client` without adding a path to it, then Bash will look for it only in the directories listed in `$PATH` (`/bin`, `/usr/bin` and so on) and fail to do it. That is a big difference from windows cmd shell.

Answer (score 1):

When you start gdb, you need to tell it which binary (executable) to debug:

```
$ gdb ./sample_client
```

Then, to run the program inside gdb, use the [`run` command](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html#Starting):

```
(gdb) run
```

You should probably give the [fine documentation](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) some quality time.

Answer (score 0):

```
gdb <binary file here>
run < <flags here>
```

Also, refer to this quick reference for future operations:
http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs107/other/gdbrefcard.pdf