# Why does my Bash code fail when I run it with 'sh'?

Tags: bash, sh, substitution

I have a line of code that works fine in my terminal:

```
for i in *.mp4; do echo ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i/.mp4/.mp3}"; done
```

Then I put the exact same line of code in a script `myscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in *.mp4; do echo ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i/.mp4/.mp3}"; done
```

However, now I get an error when running it:

```
$ sh myscript.sh
myscript.sh: 2: myscript.sh: Bad substitution
```

Based on other questions I tried changing the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to `#!/bin/bash`, but I get the exact same error. Why can't I run this script?

Comment: Are you using #!/bin/sh or #!/bin/bash from the script?

Comment: In console, the commands were executed by `bash` shell. If you are using `#!/bin/sh` in your script, it is `sh` shell trying to execute and hence the error.

Comment: I wrote #!/bin/sh in the first line...

Comment: ${foo/bar/baz} is not POSIX, and therefore may not work with your particular /bin/sh. Use `#!/bin/bash` instead. @MichaWiedenmann should suggest that as an answer.

Comment: OK, if i execute it with    bash instead of    sh it works.

Comment: To find out which sh you are using: `readlink -f $(which sh)`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

TL;DR: Since you are using Bash specific features, your script has to run with Bash and not with `sh`:

```
$ sh myscript.sh
myscript.sh: 2: myscript.sh: Bad substitution

$ bash myscript.sh
ffmpeg -i bar.mp4 bar.mp3
ffmpeg -i foo.mp4 foo.mp3
```

See *[Difference between sh and Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)*. To find out which sh you are using: `readlink -f $(which sh)`.

#### The best way to ensure a bash specific script always runs correctly

The best practices are to *both*:

1. Replace `#!/bin/sh` with `#!/bin/bash` (or whichever other shell your script depends on).
2. Run this script (and all others!) with `./myscript.sh` or `/path/to/myscript.sh`, without a leading `sh` or `bash`.

Here's an example:

```
$ cat myscript.sh
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.mp4
do
  echo ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i/.mp4/.mp3}"
done

$ chmod +x myscript.sh   # Ensure script is executable

$ ./myscript.sh
ffmpeg -i bar.mp4 bar.mp3
ffmpeg -i foo.mp4 foo.mp3
```

(Related: [Why ./ in front of scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331075/why-do-you-need-dot-slash-before-executable-or-script-name-to-run-it-in-bas))

#### The meaning of `#!/bin/sh`

The shebang suggests which shell the system should use to run a script. This allows you to specify `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/bin/bash` so that you don't have to remember which script is written in what language.

People use `#!/bin/sh` when they only use a limited set of features (defined by the POSIX standard) for maximum portability. `#!/bin/bash` is perfectly fine for user scripts that take advantage of useful bash extensions.

`/bin/sh` is usually symlinked to either a minimal POSIX compliant shell or to a standard shell (e.g. bash). Even in the latter case, `#!/bin/sh` may fail because `bash` will run in compatibility mode as explained in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> If bash is invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well.

#### The meaning of `sh myscript.sh`

The shebang is only used when you run `./myscript.sh`, `/path/to/myscript.sh`, or when you drop the extension, put the script in a directory in your `$PATH`, and just run `myscript`.

If you explicitly specify an interpreter, that interpreter will be used. `sh myscript.sh` will force it to run with `sh`, no matter what the shebang says. This is why changing the shebang is not enough by itself.

You should always run the script with its preferred interpreter, so prefer `./myscript.sh` or similar whenever you execute any script.

#### Other suggested changes to your script:

- It is considered good practice to quote variables (`"$i"` instead of `$i`). Quoted variables will prevent problems if the stored file name contains white space characters.
- I like that you use advanced [parameter expansion](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash). I suggest to use `"${i%.mp4}.mp3"` (instead of `"${i/.mp4/.mp3}"`), since `${parameter%word}` only substitutes at the end (for example a file named `foo.mp4.backup`).

Comment: +1 - It also depends on the way it is executed, I.E. You can't declare as `#!/bin/bash` then invoke with `sh` Or declare as `#!/bin/sh` and invoke with `bash`, at least on Debian 7 you will see a error on both. The declaration needs to match the invocation.

Comment: I think using `#!/usr/bin/env bash` would be a better way.

Comment: To find out which sh you are using: `readlink -f $(which sh)`

Comment: @hxysayhi I moved your comment to the answer. Feel free to update/improve the answer if there is anything you can see, which helps further readers.

Answer (score 10):

The `${var/x/y/}` construct is not POSIX. In *your* case, where you just remove a string at the end of a variable and tack on another string, the portable POSIX solution is to use

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in *.mp4; do
    ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.mp4}.mp3"
done
```

or even shorter, `ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%4}3"`.

The definitive dope for these constructs is the chapter on [Parameter Expansion for the POSIX shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02).