# How to pass the output from one command as value of argument of the next command

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I want to pass the result of a command as a **value** of an argument of the next command. I know there is `xargs` and pipe `|` but those don't really help.

I want to run the command `tail -f --pid=$REMOTE_PID logs` where REMOTE_PID is the PID of a program which is running on a **remote server.** It writes digits from 1 to 30 in a log file and `sleep(1)`. So I want to display simultaneously the digits coming from the log file on the local machine. **All this is done in a script, not manually !!**

Here is what I have done so far but can't get the correct PID. In the first command, I put the & to release the shell, so that I can run the next command

```sh
ssh user@host 'nohup sh showdigits.sh' &
ssh user@host 'PID=`pgrep -f showdigits.sh` && tail --pid=$PID -f logs'
```

These commands work but I get several PIDs before gitting the right one:

tail: cannot open '8087' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: cannot open '8109' for reading: No such file or directory
==> logs <==
1
2
3
...

I tried another code :

```sh
ssh user@host 'nohup sh showdigits.sh' & 
ssh user@host "ps -ef | awk '/[s]howdigits.sh/{print $2}' > pid && tail --pid=`cat pid` -f logs"
```

I get this error :
cat: pid: No such file or directory
tail: : invalid PID

I want to have the only one PID of the script `showdigits.sh` and pass it to tail. Maybe is there a simpler solution ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your strategy is:

1. Start a process
2. Disconnect and forget about it
3. Reconnect and try to find it
4. Follow it

You can simplify it by dropping step 2 and 3 entirely:

```
ssh user@host '
  nohup sh showdigits.sh &
  tail --pid=$! -f logs
'
```

(NB: using `sh` to run a script is a [worst practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179446/why-does-my-bash-code-fail-when-i-run-it-with-sh/15185640))

Comment: I'd also generally advise against using `nohup` here -- if you know the remote shell is bash (and the question *is* tagged `bash`, not `sh`), it could be dropped entirely in favor of explicit redirections + `disown`.

Answer (score 0):

your grep is matching more than 1 result. first match is assigned to --pid= and others are interpreted as file names.
you have to pass it through head (or tail) before processing (depending on which pid you want)
`PID=$(pgrep -f showdigits.sh | head -n1)`