# Escape charactors getting removed in echo statement

Tags: bash, shell

Original string getting mutated while printing with echo statement.

```
#!/bin/bash

response='{\\\"test\\\":\\\"data\\\"}'
echo $response;
```

Actual Output - `{\\"test\\":\\"data\\"}`

Expected output - `{\\\"test\\\":\\\"data\\\"}`

Comment: I see the output is correct: http://ideone.com/wWO8vc.

Comment: How are you running the script? Your actual output is what I would expect from a POSIX-compliant implementation of `echo`, which `bash` does not (by default) provide.

Comment: For anyone saying it "works for me": different versions of `echo` have different behavior. Some interpret escapes, some don't, some only interpret them if given the `-e` option, and some will print the "-e" as part of their output. It's all hopelessly inconsistent. According to the [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), "It is not possible to use `echo` portably across all POSIX systems unless both `-n` (as the first argument) and escape sequences are omitted." So use `printf` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. quote your variables (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)
2. use `printf`, not `echo` (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/133219)

e.g.:

```
$ response='{\\\"test\\\":\\\"data\\\"}'
$ printf '%s\n' "$response"
{\\\"test\\\":\\\"data\\\"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected in bash, but you are instead running it with `sh`. See: [Why does my bash code fail when I run it with sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179446/why-does-my-bash-code-fail-when-i-run-it-with-sh)

However, when you want to print a string exactly as is, use `printf`:

```
response='{\\\"test\\\":\\\"data\\\"}'
printf '%s\n' "$response"
```

This works correctly for all values in all shells, including `response='*'` `reponse='-n'` and `response='foo       bar'`