# Bash conditional fails when run in Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

The following conditional works as expected when run from the bash command line on my Jenkins server:

```
if (($BRANCH_COUNT > 0)); then .....
```

But when running in the context of a Jenkins pipeline step (calling `sh ''' .... '''`), it writes an error and always evaluates to false. The error message (below) suggests maybe it's interpreting the value of $BRANCH_COUNT (in this case it is 1) as a command, which is then not found?

```
/var/jenkins/workspace/deploy-config-db-update@tmp/durable-baa54bb3/script.sh: 16: 
/var/jenkins/workspace/deploy-config-db-update@tmp/durable-baa54bb3/script.sh: 1: not found
```

Is there something different about the bash environment when run by the Jenkins `sh` command? Some special escaping or quoting needed?

Comment: Using `(())` is a bashism.  Try `if test "$BRANCH_COUNT" -gt 0; then ...`

Comment: Somewhat related: [Why does my bash code fail when I run it with sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179446/why-does-my-bash-code-fail-when-i-run-it-with-sh)

Comment: William was right. Avoiding the bash-specific construction was the answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you use `sh'''...'''`, the pipeline script variable will not be expanded in your shell script. You need to use `sh """..."""`

Comment: I think it's something else.  Other $VARIABLEs are being expanded within the triple-single-quoted script.

Comment: Groovy (i.e. pipeline syntax) won't expand variables in (triple) single-quotes, but it will in (triple) double quotes. Of course, it you want bash to expand you variable,and not the pipeline script, then you want single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Moving William Pursell's comment into an answer, because it solved the problem.

> Using (()) is a bashism. Try if test "$BRANCH_COUNT" -gt 0; then ...