# bad substitution bash equivalent in sh

Tags: bash, variables, sh, alpine-linux

I have this script in Bash :

```
for conffile in $(ls -1 ${KSCFGISOLINUXFILESLOCATION}); do
  for variable in CFG_CRYPT CFG_DISK CFG_DNS CFG_DOMAIN CFG_GATEWAY CFG_HOSTNAME CFG_IFACE CFG_IP CFG_NETMASK CFG_USERKEY CFG_ACTION CFG_TITLE CFG_INITURL CFG_OSVERS CFG_ISOBASE CFG_ISOPATH CFG_ISOPATH_SIMPLE SHI_BOOT_URL DEBUG UUID LOGDIR WWWDIR OSINITDIR WKGDIR; do
    SUBSTITUTIONCOUNT=$( grep -c "%%${variable}%%" ${conffile} | cut -f1 -d" " )
    if [ ${SUBSTITUTIONCOUNT} -gt 0 ]; then
      echo "Modifying ${variable} in ${SUBSTITUTIONCOUNT} places" 
      echo "Updating ${variable} in ${conffile} to ${-variable}" 
      sed -i "s^%%${variable}%%^${-variable}^g" ${conffile} 2>&1
    fi
  done
done
```

and when I ran it in a sh shell it throws the following error:

```
/tmp/wf_script-JI1La1/rhel84isoinstall.sh: 158: /tmp/wf_script-JI1La1/rhel84isoinstall.sh: Bad substitution
```

The problem is that I'm trying to use a bash command in a sh shell

What would be the equivalent of `${!variable}` in sh ?

I tried `${-variable}` but it was a bad command.

Comment: [ShellCheck's suggestion](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC3053) is either running it with Bash, or making careful use of `eval`

Comment: The script you show doesn't use indirect expansion anywhere.

Comment: @thatotherguy can you post your comment as answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sh and Dash don't support this feature.

Make sure the script always runs with bash by seeing the shebang correctly and avoiding `sh myscript` (see [Why does my bash code fail when I run it with sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179446/why-does-my-bash-code-fail-when-i-run-it-with-sh))

Alternatively, rewrite it to sh using `eval`, but be careful about code injection:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
name=PATH
eval "echo \"\$$name\""
```