# Lost creating a .sh file using either echo -en or printf

Tags: shell, printf, echo

I'm trying to create a .sh file to write to a serial usb relay... on a Raspberry pi running Rasbian.
If run the following lines from the command prompt it sets the relay on/off correctly:

```sh
pi@raspberrypi:~/SerialRelay $ echo -en '\xa0\x01\x01\xa2' | sudo dd of=/dev/usbrelay1-1.3
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
4 bytes copied, 0.00693582 s, 0.6 kB/s
pi@raspberrypi:~/SerialRelay $ echo -en '\xa0\x01\x00\xa1' | sudo dd of=/dev/usbrelay1-1.3
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
4 bytes copied, 0.0075318 s, 0.5 kB/s
```

however if I add this to a .sh file and run, it fails to set on/off the relay with the lines output:

```sh
pi@raspberrypi:~/SerialRelay $ sudo ./Relay1.sh
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
21 bytes copied, 0.00726782 s, 2.9 kB/s
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
21 bytes copied, 0.00732381 s, 2.9 kB/s
pi@raspberrypi:~/SerialRelay $
```

I have run `chmod 777` and `ldconfig` on the .sh and I have also tried amending the .sh file with `printf` rather than `echo -en` commands. Both `echo -en` or `printf` works ok when run from the command line.

Please can anyone offer help.

Comment: You have to make sure it runs with Bash. Use `#!/bin/bash` as the shebang in your script file

Comment: Add the contents of `Relay1.sh` to your question

Comment: Also many thanks to @thatotherguy other guy for setting me on the right path. All working now.

Comment: @David C. Rankin The .sh file is:-
    echo -en '\xa0\x01\x01\xa2' | sudo dd of=/dev/usbrelay1-1.3
     sleep 1
     echo -en '\xa0\x01\x00\xa1' | sudo dd of=/dev/usbrelay1-1.3
     sleep 3
     echo -en '\xa0\x01\x01\xa2' | sudo dd of=/dev/usbrelay1-1.3
sleep 1
echo -en '\xa0\x01\x00\xa1' | sudo dd of=/dev/usbrelay1-1.3

My coffee maker automatically shuts off after 30 minutes ( another EU legislation). The .sh file mimics the toggle on/off button and is to inserted into crontab to switch the machine off/on every 20 minutes.

Comment: Sorry I don't get the code edit :-(

Comment: I must have been unclear, Edit your question and copy and paste your `Relay1.sh` script INTO your question, either indented by 4-spaces so it formats as fixed-text or place `\`\`\`bash` on the line above it and `\`\`\`` on the line below it to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

`echo -ne` and `printf '\x..'` are not portable constructs, and therefore don't work the same between shells. You tested your code in Bash, but ran your script with Dash.

You can either:

- run the script with Bash, as detailed in [Why does my Bash code fail when I run it with 'sh'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15185640/1899640)
- Rewrite it portably using `printf` octal escapes, e.g. `printf '\240\001\001\242'`

Comment: I missed a bit out of the .sh when I copied it to the comment. I am using #!/bin/bash at the start of the .sh file.