# Unable to output script results with column/table formatting

Tags: linux, bash, cron, scripting

**Answered - previously titled 'Cron job for shell script not running'**

I recently downloaded Speedtest onto my Raspberry Pi, and wrote a script to output the results in csv format to a CSV file.

I'm trying to do this regularly via a cron job, but for some reason, it won't execute the shell script as intended.

Here's the script below. I've commented/cut out a lot to try and find the issue

```
#!/bin/bash

# Commented out if statement detects presence of data file and creates one if it doesn't exist. Was going to adjust later to include variables/input options if I wanted to used script on alternate systems, but commented out while working on main issue.

file='/home/User/Documents/speedtestdata.csv' 
# have tried this with and without quotes, does not seem to make a difference either way
#HEADERS='/usr/bin/speedtest-cli --csv-header'

SPEEDTEST='/usr/bin/speedtest-cli --csv'
# Used absolute path for the executable

#LOG=/home/User/scripts/testreclog.txt
#DATE=$( date )
# Was using the above to log steps of script running successfully with timestamp, commented out 

#if [ ! -f $file ]
#then
#       echo "Creating results file">>$LOG
#       touch $file
#       $HEADERS > $file
#fi

#echo "Running speedtest">>$LOG

$SPEEDTEST >> $file

#echo "Formatting results">>$LOG

#column -s, -t < $file
# this step was used to format the log file neatly

#echo "Time completed ",$DATE>>$LOG
```

And here's how the crontab currently looks

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').
#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command

*/5 * * * * /bin/bash /home/User/scripts/testandrec.sh

# 2> /home/User/scripts/testrecerror.txt
# Was attempting to log errors to this file, nothing seen so commented out on a newline.

#* * * * * /home/User/scripts/testscript.sh test to verify cron works (it does)
```

I've added my scripts folder to the end of my path, but for some reason this only shows up when I'm using the Pi directly, when I ssh in I'm missing the scripts folder on the end.
However, given that I've used absolute path for everything I'm not sure why this would be an issue.

First I tested whether a simple Cron job would work, so I created testscript.sh, which simply returned 'Test' and a timestamp to a specific file and used the same shebang, and used the absolute paths, and functioned as intended.

I have checked systemctl for Cron, restarted Cron with `sudo service cron restart` and made sure a new line is in place in the crontab.

I have tried with and without `/bin/bash` in the cron tab entry, it seemingly hasn't made a difference.

I tried `cd /home/User/scripts && ./testandrec.sh` but no luck.

I changed the run time to every 5 then every 10 minutes, which has not worked.

I *have* noticed that when I ran the script manually with `column -s, -t < $file` left in, when cating the results file it is formatted as intended.
However, the next instance of when the cron job should run reverts this to CSV with a , as a delimitter, so clearly *something* is running.

To confuse matters further, I think the script may be firing once after restarting cron, and then not working when it should be running subsequently. When I leave the column line in, this appears to just revert the formatting, but if I comment it out it appears to run a speed test and append the results, but only once. However, I may be wrong on this and reproducing it

If I instead try `0 * * * * /usr/bin/speedtest-cli --csv >> /home/User/Documents/speedtestdata.csv && column -s, -t < /home/User/Documents/speedtestdata.csv`, it appeared to perform/append speedtest but does not action the column command.

I would much rather neatly tie up the process in a shell script, however, rather than have the above which isn't very DRY code.

I've looked extensively, but none of the solutions I've found on this site or others have fixed the issue.

Any troubleshooting suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IMO, `cron` is a bad piece of software (all 5+ variations of it) and a bad idea in general. To properly schedule, debug, log, security-harden and otherwise master periodic tasks, use `systemd` `timer` units. I’ve been recommending this quite often [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73225460/cronjob-working-partially-with-if-condition-only-picks-else-part#comment129323480_73225460), [(2)](https://superuser.com/questions/1684403/script-in-crontab-only-partially-executed#comment2586978_1684403) + more comments below (as some users are … stubborn, diplomatically said).

Comment: I don't think you've given us a proper description of your failure mode despite all the wordiness. The script as shown above works just fine. It also works just fine run from `cron` (at least on my pi running raspian) every two minutes.  I have a sneaky suspicion that the "doesn't work" part solely hinges on the `column` ...

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek - nice opinion plug, but this doesn't address the problem at hand or even offer an attempt at clarifying debug info.

Comment: @tink - Yeah, I've gotten the cron job to work with column commented out. I tried using the absolute path for column in order somewhat permanently have the results in a table format, but I think I've misunderstood how column works. I'm guessing it's only used as a way to view files rather than permanently edit their structure?

Comment: That's right. I'll give you a working version as an answer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go - the solution is simple:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Commented out if statement detects presence of data file and creates one if it doesn't exist. Was going to adjust later to include variables/input options if I wanted to used script on alternate systems, but commented out while working on main issue.

file='/home/User/Documents/speedtestdata.csv' 
# have tried this with and without quotes, does not seem to make a difference either way
#HEADERS='/usr/bin/speedtest-cli --csv-header'

SPEEDTEST='/usr/bin/speedtest-cli --csv'
# Used absolute path for the executable

#LOG=/home/User/scripts/testreclog.txt
#DATE=$( date )
# Was using the above to log steps of script running successfully with timestamp, commented out 

#if [ ! -f $file ]
#then
#       echo "Creating results file">>$LOG
#       touch $file
#       $HEADERS > $file
#fi

#echo "Running speedtest">>$LOG

$SPEEDTEST | column -s, -t >> $file
```

Just check the last line ;)

Comment: Oh goddammit, it was right there! Cheers dude :'D

Comment: Yeah .. the problem with your approach is that column would have printed to stdout, so you probably have a ton of emails from cron with the formatted output ;)

Comment: @user357938 - now that we've established that cron wasn't at fault at all - maybe edit your question respectively? ;) Something along the lines of: *not getting columnated output in my file*

Comment: Done and done :D

Comment: Good person :) - thank you, @user357938