# Making perl scripts executable... can I do away with the preceding 'perl' statement?

Tags: linux, perl, unix, shebang

This is a pretty simple one... I just want to make a perl script executable without the preceding `perl` command, and instead let the environment deduce the interpreter from the shebang line. Here is my sample script called `test`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Hey there\n";
```

I then use `chmod 775 test` to make the script executable. If I use the command `perl test`, I get the output `Hey there`.

However, if I just type `test`, I get no output. What's the deal? Why isn't my shebang line making the environment realize this is perl? Can someone please help me?

Comment: Try `./test` or put your script somewhere in the path.

Comment: Try renaming your script. `test` is a built-in command in most shells.

Comment: See SO question [Why do you need ./ (dot-slash) before script name to run it in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331075/why-do-you-need-dot-slash-before-script-name-to-run-it-in-bash)

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to mention the folder I was working in was already added to $PATH. And yes, the problem was that I named the file test! `Sample` worked. thanks!

Comment: So, my example script works, but the software I'm trying to get running doesn't. I get the error message: `bash: /usr/bin/SampleSoftware: /usr/bin/perl^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`. What is going on here? I thought I had a bad line ending after my `shebang` line, but I don't think that is the case

Comment: Run `dos2unix` on your script.

Comment: Also, you're now asking a completely different question, invalidating all the existing answers. Don't do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't name your script `test`. This is a built-in command in most shells, so they don't go looking for an external program.

Also, to run a program in your current directory, you should type `./programname`. It's generally a bad idea to have `.` in your `$PATH`, which would be necessary to execute it without the directory prefix.

Answer (score 0):

To run something from the current directory you need to prefix "./" to tell it "this directory" ie `./testprogram`.

If you type just `test` it will look in standard install directories like /bin. This is why when you run `cp` or `rm` it knows where the executable is.

As mentioned by others, naming scripts `test` is not allowed with most shells.

Comment: In the specific case of `test`, most shells won't look anywhere, because they implement it as a builtin, which takes precedence over external binaries.

Comment: Edited to remove reference to `test`