# Running a Unix executable from the command line

Tags: unix

If I am in a directory `foo`, that contains executable `bar`, why does typing `bar` results in

> bar: command not found

whereas typing `./bar` works?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do you need ./ (dot-slash) before script name to run it in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331075/why-do-you-need-dot-slash-before-script-name-to-run-it-in-bash)

Answer (score 4):

Because, by default, the *nix $PATH doesn't include the current directory.  Believe it or not, this is a Good Thing:

[Why do you need ./ (dot-slash) before script name to run it in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331075/why-do-you-need-dot-slash-before-script-name-to-run-it-in-bash)

[Linux doesn't automatically add current directory to PATH](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/miscellaneous/27942-linux-doesnt-automatically-add-current-directory-path.html)

> No, it is not made to be "annoying". It is for security good practice.
>   Imaging you write a script and call it "ls" then save it in a folder
>   where you have access, let's say /tmp. Now if you get your admin to
>   run "ls" in /tmp as root and have "." in the PATH, that will run your
>   script instead of running the real "ls". This way you can do some
>   nasty trick. This is why "." is not in your PATH. Now if you don't
>   need this kind of security, then modify your PATH.

There's nothing that prevents you from modifying your $PATH.  On Linux, ".bashrc" in your home directory is a good place.  If you add ".", you should add it to the *END* of your $PATH, not the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, "bar" doesn't work because "./" isn't in your PATH environment variable. You can verify this by typing

```
echo $PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

Because as opposed to windows, the current directory is not in the `$PATH`. So your shell won't try to look for a command name `bar` in the current folder unless you tell it to look there.