# yii2 error when trying to install all generats files

Tags: php, frameworks, yii2

When I am trying to type `init --env=Development --overwrite=n` in command line on Linux

I have  an error bash: --env=Development: command not found

Comment: are you using `./init --env=Development --overwrite=n` ?

Comment: no, but when I did   ./init --env=Development --overwrite=n    I've made it, thanks))

Comment: added it as an answer so it can be accepted to close the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux, for security purposes, you have to refer to the current directory specifically.

You will have to use

`./init --env=Development --overwrite=n`

Also [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6331085/50158) for a more extensive explanation.