# -bash: pgrmname: command not found

Tags: bash, command-line

I'm new in programming and I'm running into a problem. When I want to compile the program (cop) everything is ok but when I want to execute the program I have this: " :-bash:prgmname: command not found "

[image]

I don't understand why, it never happened before. I don't know if it'll help but I'm using Sublime Text. I tried to look at similar questions but I don't understand the answers... Sorry if my question sounds stupid but please answer if you have any idea why it does this and how to solve it.

Comment: Try this: `./cop`.

Comment: See: [Why do you need ./ (dot-slash) before script name to run it in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6331075/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

By doing

```
 cop
```

the command line interpreter will look for the standard bin directories, say `/bin` for the command. What you should do is

```
./cop
```

This searches the file in the current directory