# How run Modelsim with vsim command in terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, modelsim

Now I'm can run it with ./vsim command from folder /quartus/modelsim_ase/linuxaloem

when I'm put vsim, get

```
No command 'vsim' found, did you mean: ...
```

but when I'm try run leon3 simulation from grlib via make vsim-launch I'm get

```
/bin/sh: 1: vsim: not found
```

Comment: Looks like you need to put the `vsim` executable in your path.

Comment: I'm find answer for my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331075/why-do-you-need-dot-slash-before-script-name-to-run-it-in-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to the bin directory of the Modelsim installation and do './vsim' . If that works add the bin path to your ~/.bashrc