# Install SpiderMonkey 45 failed in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, spidermonkey

I tried to install SpiderMonkey 45  in Ubuntu 16.04, but I failed. I refered to [SpiderMonkey Build Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Build_Documentation) and finished the make process.

```
cd js/src
autoconf-2.13

mkdir build_DBG.OBJ
cd build_DBG.OBJ
../configure --enable-debug --disable-optimize
make
```

After the installation, when I change the directory to `../build_DEBUG.OPT/js/src/shell` and type `js`, the terminal gave me an error:

```
The program 'js' can be found in the following packages:
 * nodejs
 * rhino
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

How to solve the problem?  Thank you very much.

Comment: Does the executable `js` exist in that directory? If so, try `./js` instead.

Comment: Yeah, it works for me as you said. But why `./js` works and 'js' doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `js` directly looks in your `PATH` environment variable for an executable called `js`. Since the directory that you built Spidermonkey in **isn't in your path**, the executable isn't found, causing an error.

`./js` expands to `<your current directory>/js`, which is specific enough for your terminal to find the executable and run it.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331075/why-do-you-need-dot-slash-before-script-name-to-run-it-in-bash) for a more general explanation as to why `./executable` works but `executable` doesn't.

Comment: Don't forget to accept this (and any answers to your other questions) if it's helpful with the green tick icon.