# Invoke a C program by typing *just* the name of the executable in command?

Tags: unix, command-line

So typically a program  with an argument is invoked in the following way:

> ./helloworld -test

I've been asked to invoke a C program in command-line simply by typing:

> helloworld test

In other words, without the "./". I should be able to launch my program in a Unix command-line just as I would "ls". The tools I currently have (that I am aware of) at my disposal to make this happen are Makefile and argv[], but I can't find any questions or documentation on the internet relevant to this particular problem.

Comment: You can execute a program by name if the directory where the program is located is in the `$PATH`.

Comment: Do an `export PATH=${PATH}:./` prior to running your program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do you need ./ (dot-slash) before script name to run it in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6331075/1072229)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `PATH` variable contains the `./` directory (or better the full path), to run the program without specifying the directory.

Comment: This is generally *not* recommended.

Comment: @EOF Sure, adding `./` to the `PATH` variable is a bad idea.