# setsid is not working, giving error

Tags: linux, shell, setsid

I want to run a script as a process. so running below command,

```
setsid test.sh > test.log &
```

But giving error as below,

```
setsid: failed to execute test.sh: No such file or directory
```

Whats wrong here? I have test.sh file with execute permission in current location.

Comment: does test.sh file have execute permissions for test.sh ? (ls -l test.sh should tell you) If it doesn't use chmod +x test.sh to give one.

Comment: Yes it has execute permission.   -rwxrwxrwx   1 nitesh nitesh    15 Jan 11 13:49 test.sh

Comment: does it have execute permission for the same user for which you are trying ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6331085/13422

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as if you were running it without `setsid` you need to *tell it* to execute with a complete path.

```
setsid ./test.sh > test.log &
```