# Run Python code without using python name.py and ./name

Tags: python

I have a basic problem where I don't know how to run a Python script from command line in Ubuntu without using python keyword. So, I put a shebang in my Python script so I could run it as nameofthescript from the command line, but I only could do it by using ./nameofthescript. I want to be able to run it by just typing the name of the script in the cmd. I searched and tried everything I could on the web, but none is working. Any help is appreciated. Below is a simple code I wrote to test it.

## I already tried chmod +x `this file`. Also this file is saved with no extension.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

def main(argv):
    print(argv)
    print("Hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: You need to put the script on your `$PATH`, by putting it in a directory listed by typing `echo $PATH` on the commandline.

Comment: I have tried that, and still couldnt get it to work. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to solve this. I still include the shebang #!/usr/bin/env python3.6 at the top of Python script. Then I would go to cd /etc->sudo nano bash.bashrc, and at the very last line, all I did was add a line (alias nameofscript = "./nameofscript"). From there I restarted my Ubuntu, and was able to run my Python script just by the name of the script. Thank you everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your $PATH variable.

When you go to run a command (without the "./" in front of it) Ubuntu looks in all the folders listed in your $PATH variable. Your can see it by running:

```
echo $PATH
```

If Ubuntu doesn't see the command in any of those folders, it will say that it can't be found.

You can solve this problem by altering your $PATH variable in your profile. Go to your home directory and open the ".profile" file (note the period in front) and add the following to the end:

```
PATH = "/path/to/folder/with/file/:$PATH"
```

However, if it's a program you could see yourself using a lot in the future and your don't want to clutter up your $PATH, I'd recommend sticking the finished command in your "/usr/local/bin" folder instead. I find that folder gets used as an "odd sock drawer" of programs you create/compile yourself, so I usually end up putting my personal tools in there rather than modifying my $PATH.

Comment: That is very useful to know, thank you for pointing that out. I have tried putting my exec file in /usr/local/bin, but in the cmd when I typed nameofscript,nothing happened. However, like I have mentioned, when I typed ./nameofscript, the codes ran.

Comment: Interesting. Just for clarification, when you say “nothing happened” do you mean that there was no output at all and it waited for the next command, or was there a “command not found” message of some kind? Also, what output do you get from “echo $PATH”?

Comment: Yeah, it just waited for the next command line. It does not print anything for me.  This is the output I got from running echo $PATH 
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: Okay so the path is good. I tried running code on my machine and it worked fine. Try putting a “print(‘Hello’)” immediately after the import statement. If it prints “Hello”, then we know the OS is finding the file I’d suspect there may be a typo in your original code that is not in the lines you posted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

That's how it's supposed to work, not only for Python scripts but for any executable. See: [Why do you need ./ (dot-slash) before executable or script name to run it in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331075/why-do-you-need-dot-slash-before-executable-or-script-name-to-run-it-in-bas)

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this one

On unix systems, Python scripts can be made executable using the following process:

**Add this line as the first line in the script:**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

At the unix command prompt, type the following to make myexe.py executable:

```sh
$ chmod +x myexe.py
```

Move **myexe.py** into your `bin` directory, and it will be runnable from anywhere.

```sh
$ cp myexe.py /usr/bin
```

OR

```sh
$ cp myexe.py /usr/local/bin
```

**So myexe.py**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("Hello This is executable python script")
```

Now Go to terminal and type myexe.py

```sh
$ myexe.py
Hello This is excutable python script
```

If you want to **run by double-clicking** remove .py extention

[source link](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/app_c.html)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tried that, and I still have use ./ in front of the script to run it. When I tried running by typing the name of the script only, nothing happens in the terminal.