# how to use pyinstaller from mac and pycharm, with arguments

Tags: python, pycharm, pyinstaller

I am trying to create an executable file from PyCharm using Pyinstaller. I run `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed myprogram.py` That created a file in the dist folder. Now I try to run that file in pycharm console using `myprogram arg1` , the error that `myprogram command not found`

How could I create an executable and run it with command line parameters, which was required by the program? Many thanks.

Comment: thats exactly how .... are you in the dist folder when trying to execute it?

Comment: Yea I am. The file in dist folder does not seem to have an extension tho. Would that be a problem?

Comment: if its in windows it should be an exe

Comment: @JoranBeasley Im using mac

Comment: try `./myprogram arg1` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331075/why-do-you-need-dot-slash-before-executable-or-script-name-to-run-it-in-bas