# Do I need to specify ./ (dot-slash) before script name even when I specify the program which executes it?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, path, command-prompt

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6331075/7400903) on "why do you need ./ (dot-slash) before executable or script name to run it in bash?", I would like to ask if I should specify `./` before the script name even when I specify the program which executes it.

For example, each one of the following works on my system (Windows 10 command-prompt):

- `node test.js`
- `node ./test.js`
- `node .\test.js`
- `python test.py`
- `python ./test.py`
- `python .\test.py`

But I need to provide instructions for my project, and so I would like to have something which is guaranteed to work regardless of the OS in use.

For the sake of this question, please assume that the OS can run the executable program (`node` and `python` in the examples above) from any path.

Comment: Short answer: No. It might have advantages, but you don't **have to**

Comment: @oguzismail: Thanks. So it is guaranteed to work on any platform without specifying `./`?

Comment: Yes it is guaranteed, unless the filename starts with a dash

Comment: _"I would like to have something which is guaranteed to work regardless of the OS in use"_ - in which case avoid `.\test.js`, i.e. a backslash, because node.js on  _*nix_ throws: _"Error: Cannot find module"_

Comment: @RobC: As you might understand from my question, I am **not using any prefix**, and I would like to know if it's OK to keep it that way. I added those examples just in order to illustrate that on my system everything works (thus implying that I cannot use this info in order to determine whether or not refraining from the "dot-slash" prefix would work on other systems).

Comment: @oguzismail: Thanks. AFAIK, file and folder names cannot contains slashes of any form (only paths can).

Comment: Not slash, a dash, a hyphen, i.e `-`

Comment: @oguzismail: Oh... sorry, missed that. Thank you very much in that case. You can post that as an answer then.

Comment: @goodvibration : Just for clarificiation, since Your wording _to run it in bash_  is ambiguous. For instance, it makes in general a difference whether you have to use `./myscript.sh` as a command of its own, or `myscript.sh`. The general rule is that whenever a program is looking up a filename using the usual `open` call, a relativ path is always taken relative to the working directory, and this is why your examples with `node ....` and `python ....` do indeed work.

Comment: @goodvibration - Yes, reading your question again does seem like I'm stating the obvious in my previous comment - apologies for that. Given your examples, there is no functional difference between; with `./` or without it - it's a matter of preference. However, as you say; _" I need to provide instructions"_, one could argue that by including `./` it helps to indicatively inform the user their current working directory prior to invoking the `node/python` command should be the same as where `test.(js|py)` resides.

Comment: @goodvibration - **sidenote:** Given your node example the `.js` suffix is also not necessary. Running `node test` or ``node ./test`` also works. However, in a similar way that `./` is indicative, including the `.js` suffix is indicative too.

Comment: @RobC: Yes, I'm aware of that, but I want to keep compatibility with other programs (python included).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It might have advantages on some cases, but you don't always have to prepend the name of a script residing in the current working directory with a `./`. If its name starts with a hyphen (`-`) (or any other character recognized by the interpreter to introduce an option/flag, like a backslash, a plus sign etc.), prepending it with `./` might be required for some interpreters though, but apparently that's not the case here.

So just go with

```
nodejs test.js
python test.py
```