# Can't run java from bin folder

Tags: java, linux

Linux Mint 19.3.

Content of `/home/alexei/.bash_profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jre1.8.0_251
```

here folder with jre

[image]

But when I run `java` from **bin** folder I get error:

```
java -version

Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install default-jre            
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

How I can fix this?

Comment: `./java`, not `java`, since you're trying to run from the current directory.

Comment: Is that folder in your `PATH`?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes,  I updated my post

Comment: That's `JAVA_HOME`, not `PATH`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca After this: export PATH="/usr/java/jre1.8.0_251/bin:$PATH" , then I success run java -version from any folder. Thank

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior. `cd`'ing to a directory does not make the programs available like it does in Windows cmd.exe.

To run a file in the current directory, you can instead use `./java -version`

(Related: [Why do you need ./ (dot-slash) before executable or script name to run it in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331075/why-do-you-need-dot-slash-before-executable-or-script-name-to-run-it-in-bas)).

To be able to run `java` from any directory, first see if your distro has a mechanism in place (e.g. `update-alternatives --config java`). If not, you can always manually [add the directory to your `PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix).