# Function of ./ (dot slash) in .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I recently came across a [.gitignore file](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/.gitignorehttps://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397524/what-does-the-mean-dot-slash-in-linux) that started some newlines with `./`. I had no idea what those `./`s did, and I was very surprised to find out that this was both a) a seemingly novel question, and b) very hard to find answers for.

I've seen [these](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397524/what-does-the-mean-dot-slash-in-linux) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331075/why-do-you-need-dot-slash-before-executable-or-script-name-to-run-it-in-bas) questions, but the function of `./` in gitignores seems to be different from that in the bash terminal.

My testing seems to indicate that `./` just doesn't do anything. Given a folder structure:

```
C:.
│   .gitignore
├───bar
│       bar0.txt
├───baz
│       baz0.txt
└───foo
        foo0.txt
```

And a .gitignore

```
# .gitignore
./foo
./foo/*
./foo/
bar
/baz
```

If I do `git add -A` and `git status`, only these files are tracked:

```
new file:   .gitignore
new file:   foo/foo0.txt
```

So, what is the purpose of `./`?

Edit: I'm on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

Remember that in both Windows (and DOS) and Unix (including macOS) a singular dot in a file-path `.` refers to the current-directory.

From the `.gitignore` documentation, the relevant points are:

> - The slash `/` is used as the directory separator. Separators may occur at the beginning, middle or end of the `.gitignore` search pattern.
> - If there is a separator at the beginning or middle (or both) of the pattern, then the pattern is relative to the directory level of the particular `.gitignore` file itself. Otherwise the pattern may also match at any level below the `.gitignore` level.

So:

- `foo`

  - will match any file-or-directory named `foo` in the same directory **and** any descendant directories relative to the `.gitignore` file.
- `./foo`

  - will match only a file-or-directory named `foo` *in the same directory* as the `.gitignore` file.
  - I note that even though the git manual says it matches “files or directories” remember that this is **not** recursive - nor does it match files in that subfolder (nor other subdirectories) without the `**` glob wildcard. I don’t know why the manual says “files or directories” when `git` itself doesn’t store any information relating to directories - only files.
- `/foo`

  - will behave the same as `./foo`.
- `./foo/`

  - will match only a directory named `foo` *in the same directory* as the `.gitignore` file.
- `/foo/`

  - will behave the same as `./foo/`.

As for why someone used `./` as a prefix instead of just `/`, I can only speculate, but some reasons might by:

- They wanted to use a syntax that made it immediately clear to a reader unfamiliar with `.gitignore`'s rules that the specified path is relative to the `.gitignore` file's directory, as `/foo` (without a leading `.`) could be interpreted as an absolute-path (that's either filesystem-absolute, especially on Linux, e.g. `/usr/bin` - or an absolute path inside the git repo)
- They generated the `.gitignore` file by piping the output from another program or utility that used leading `.` in its output.
- They themselves were unaware of the rules and this is just an example of [Cargo Cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) (i.e. doing things a particular way (especially when it's elaborate) without understanding *why* they're doing it that way, and without investigating if it's necessary).

Comment: That's what I thought what would happen, but with my test case `./foo` doesn't tell git to ignore the directory `foo` or "foo0.txt", like what I thought `/foo` would do  (at least on my machine).

Comment: @phlaxyr That’s right - because it isn’t using the syntax to exclude the contents of subdirectories recursively (that would be `/foo/**`). I admit my answer was incomplete because git does not store directories, only files. But it is interesting that the git manual implies it does.

Comment: @Dai: while Git doesn't *store* directories (because you can't get one into Git's index), it does *understand* them in the host-file-system tree-walking code, and the ignore stuff makes use of this to do shortcut exclusion of entire subtrees, to avoid lots of `lstat` calls. That's where most of the "doesn't store directories, but does know about them" internal conflict comes from.

Comment: @Dai Yeah, but even when I put a file `foo/foo0.txt` in `foo/`, git adds `foo0.txt` even though i have `./foo` in the .gitignore.

Comment: I put my updated test case [here](https://gist.github.com/phlaxyr/12954dca2a5ff0a251b6c0a9df4ae736)