# Code not running from terminal in vs code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

[image]

Image is showing that when i used terminal to run the code, it wont run. code is running perfectly in output section, opened vs code after a month and shows this type of output in terminal

Comment: You are just compiling the code

Comment: You may want to try this VSCode tutorial: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just compiling the code, not running it. To run the code, type the following:

```
./exe_name.exe
```

..or in your case:

```
./tut4.exe
./tut5.exe
```

If you're using a mac machine, just replace `.exe` with `.out`

Comment: I answered the question just so that it can stand out and help someone who's starting out to code.

Comment: Those who started out programming should read a good book / follow a good tutorial. In that process if they genuinely find a certain problem which is not available on google / other sites (they also researched well), then they should ask on SO.

Comment: i am new to this coding world and i am learning on my own, so when i get any error stackovrflow community is the first thing in my mind. i appreciate @SolvedGames who just helped me.

Comment: You probably should spend a little time googling how to use the command line and how to build code from the command line.

Comment: I agree with @Darth-CodeX

Comment: @VedantDomadiya Use google to find your answer, also google will refer you to stackoverflow, and those question have already been answered 10+ years ago

Comment: For example: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=run+executable+file+in+linux

Comment: See this SO question which is answered 10+years ago https://stackoverflow.com/q/6331075/17939455