# What is POSIX compliance and how does it affect me?

Tags: unix, posix

I keep seeing this come up and every time I look it up I never get a good explanation of what it is or what it means to me.

What is POSIX compliance? How does assuming my program will only be run on POSIX-compliant machines simplify things for me as a programmer? Does it even?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I never really understood: what is POSIX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780599/i-never-really-understood-what-is-posix)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) defines a set of [C headers](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/headers.html), [System Interfaces](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/functions.html), a [Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/shell.html) and [Utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html), that a conforming system must implement.

As a developer, you can rely on these standard interfaces being available on every POSIX system. If your program uses the standard interfaces, it can operate on all POSIX systems.

Porting across non-standard systems is more work, as the system interfaces e.g. for [multithreading](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/pthread.h.html) or [networking](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/syssocket.h.html) are different.

Comment: So as long as I only stick to those C headers and System Interfaces in my code, it will run identically any POSIX system (and I will only have to recompile)?

Comment: Yes, that's the general idea. Of course you can also use external libraries and their headers if they are POSIX compatible. A recompile is all that's needed, assuming you have observed other portable coding practices, i.e. only using aligned pointers, taking care of endianness issues etc. Relying on _implementation defined_ behavior breaks portability.