# Recursively list directories in C

Tags: c

im looking for a code who will recursively list all directories and files of a directory given on argument in C programming, ive find an interresting code (below) but I dont understand the snprintf function and particulary the "/", 
I would prefer to use strcat or other system function to override the sprintf function but I dont see how since I dont understand what the snprintf do here.
Heres the code:

```
int is_directory_we_want_to_list(const char *parent, char *name) {
    struct stat st_buf;
    if (!strcmp(".", name) || !strcmp("..", name))
        return 0;

    char *path = alloca(strlen(name) + strlen(parent) + 2);
    sprintf(path, "%s/%s", parent, name);
    stat(path, &st_buf);
    return S_ISDIR(st_buf.st_mode);
}

int list(const char *name) {
    DIR *dir = opendir(name);
    struct dirent *ent;

    while (ent = readdir(dir)) {
        char *entry_name = ent->d_name;
        printf("%s\n", entry_name);

        if (is_directory_we_want_to_list(name, entry_name)) {
            // You can consider using alloca instead.
            char *next = malloc(strlen(name) + strlen(entry_name) + 2);
            sprintf(next, "%s/%s", name, entry_name);
            list(next);
            free(next);
        }
    }

    closedir(dir);
}
```

from [How to recursively list directories in C on LINUX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436841/how-to-recursively-list-directories-in-c-on-linux)

Okay, my program is running but now i want to save all the file and directory printed to a file like i run my program ./a.out . > buffer where buffer contain what the program should print on the shell

Comment: uh... what snprintf call? There's none in the code snippet. If you don't understand what it does, why don't you LOOK UP what it does? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/

Comment: what is your problem with sprintf exactly? it's just concatenating 3 strings - name, "/" and entry_name.

Comment: i think sprintf is creating all problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line

```
sprintf(next, "%s/%s", name, entry_name);
```

could be replaced with

```
strcpy (next, name);
strcat (next, "/");
strcat (next, entry_name);
```

and it would do the same thing. Does that clarify it for you?

Comment: that was fast, yes i get it a lot better now thank you, and yes it was sprintf, sorry

Comment: Do note that every call to `strcat()` involves walking the entire string to find the end of it, so a single `sprintf()` call here is much more efficient.