# Why does readdir() list ".." as one of the files?

Tags: c, linux

I am just not able to understand that why readdir() lists ".." as one of the files in the directory.
Following is my code snippet

```
while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)  
{  
    printf("%s \n", dir->d_name);  //It displayed .. once and rest of the time file names
}
```

Comment: `..` is the file that represents the parent directory, it is present in all directories.

Comment: @epicbrew I could be wrong, but I think it's usually present in the root as well; it is just a loop in the tree that points to itself. totally irrelevant, carry on.

Comment: @mfrankli yep you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` and `..` represent the current and parent directory and are present in all directories (see footnote below). `readdir()` does not filter them out as they are valid entries within a directory. You can do the following to filter them out yourself.

```
while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)  
{
    if (strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    printf("%s \n", dir->d_name);
}
```

<sub>Note: Technically, SUSv3 does not require that `.` and `..` actually be present in all directories, but does require that the OS implementation correctly interpret them when encountered within a path.</sub>

Comment: ya I already did strcmp seeing it somewhere on stackoverflow. But was not knowing the explanation of .. and . . Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

`..` is not actually a file it is a directory of the *nix file system. It represents the parent directory of the current directory. Similarly `.` is the representation of the current dirrectory. This is relevant for moving around the file tree and relative directory representations.

Take a look at this article on [changing directories](http://www.centos.org/docs/2/rhl-gsg-en-7.2/s1-navigating-cd.html):

> A cd .. tells your system to go up to the directory immediately above
>   the one in which you are currently working

Comment: Actually a directory is a file in *nix. Everything is a file in *nix. See [here for more details](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_01.html)

Comment: @epicbrew: Yes, but directory *entries* are not files; rather, they refer to files.

Answer (score 1):

It seems readdir() does not ignore '..' & '.'. So you have to filter the two files by yourself. 
This post might be helpful
[How to recursively list directories in C on LINUX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436841/how-to-recursively-list-directories-in-c-on-linux)

Answer (score 0):

`readdir()` reads the next directory entry. `..`  is a directory entry.