# Determine the type of directory entry a link points to

Tags: c, linux

I want to read subdirectories and links to subdirectories only.
With the following code I read all subdirs and links.

```
struct dirent* de;
DIR* dir = opendir(c_str());
if (!dir) { /* error handling */ }

while (NULL != (de = readdir(dir))) {
    if (de->d_type != DT_DIR && de->d_type != DT_LNK)
        continue;
    // Do something with subdirectory
 }
```

But how do I examine whether the link points to a subdirectory too? I do not want to read the entire linked directory to do this.

Comment: For what purpose did you tag this with both C and C++?

Comment: Are you looking for readlink ? http://linux.die.net/man/3/readlink

Comment: `readlink` to get the path of the pointed-to thing, `stat` for checking if it is a directory?

Comment: Related link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436841/how-to-recursively-list-directories-in-c-on-linux

Comment: It's typical to ignore symlinks to directories when recursively traversing, because of the danger of double-counting and even infinite loops.  (Well, not actually infinite, because of `ENAMETOOLONG` and `ELOOP`.)

Comment: You should always set `errno` to 0 before calling `readdir`.  It can return `NULL` either on error or when it reaches the end of the directory, so the only way to distinguish between the two is checking `errno`.  If some other function inside the loop sets `errno` and you don't reset it before calling `readdir`, you could detect a false error condition.  See the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) for details.

Answer (score 3):

You can use function named `stat` from `<sys/stat.h>`:

```
struct dirent* de;
struct stat s;
DIR* dir = opendir(c_str());
if (!dir) { /* error handling */ }

while (NULL != (de = readdir(dir))) {
    if (de->d_type != DT_DIR) {
        char filename[256];
        sprintf(filename, "%s/%s", c_str(), de->d_name);
        if (stat(filename, &s) < 0)
            continue;
        if (!S_ISDIR(s.st_mode))
            continue;
    }
    // Do something with subdirectory
}
```

Comment: @Th.Thielemann: you need to use `stat` anyway if `de->d_type` is `DT_UNKNOWN`, or you're compiling on a system that doesn't even provide a `d_type` field in `struct dirent`.  This is a real problem, because it's still a new feature for XFS filesystems.  It requires the newest format of on-disk metadata, with metadata CRCs, which isn't yet the default.  The default for `mkfs.xfs` is `-n ftype=0`, so even newly-created XFS filesystems on new installs won't support it unless the admin manually chose to enable the option.

Comment: You could still take advantage of `d_type` to avoid `stat()`ing anything other than symlinks (which might point to a directory, or might not).

Comment: `char filename[256];` and then `sprintf()` into that buffer?  That's a recipe for a buffer overflow.

Comment: That's true, but answer was about `stat` function.