# List the FULL path of all the subfolders and files inside a directory one per line in GCC

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, libc

I want to display the full path of all subfolders and files of a directory one per line in GCC. The existing questions don't provide a solution for listing the full path.

For eg,
If I have a directory /root/abc which contains two files(a.txt and b.txt) and a directory xyz, then the code must display the following

```
/root/abc
/root/abc/a.txt
/root/abc/b.txt
/root/abc/xyz
```

Comment: Which language? Which platform?

Comment: @FrankMeerkötter C language in linux platform

Comment: @FrankMeerkötter Thanks for the edit ! :)

Comment: Notice that you actually want to list the full path not *inside* the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (that would not make much sense, but you might customize the compiler with [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)...) but in a program *compiled by* GCC (and you could also compile it with another compiler, perhaps [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)...)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Actually I want to list it inside the compiler itself as I'm using this as a utility function in my program.

Comment: Are you sure you want to change the behavior of the GCC compiler (e.g. when it would compile some other program, unrelated to yours)?? Compile-time (and compiler) is not the same as run-time (and your program)...

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer ! Just made a minor change to the answer given for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436841/how-to-recursively-list-directories-in-c-on-linux) Just print the "name" attribute along with "entry->d_name" inside the listdir function.

```
printf("%*s[%s%s]\n", level*2, "", name, entry->d_name);
```

Note: Make sure that the input you provide to the function doesn't have a trailing '/' because in that case you will get "//" instead of '/' in the full path.

For example, if the input is given is /root/abc/, the output will be

```
/root/abc//a.txt
/root/abc//b.txt
/root/abc//xyz
```

Comment: You'll better use `nftw` as answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29402705/841108)

Comment: I find it hard to understand that code. This one is simple and suits my need !

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) ??